# Properly importing modules in Python

Tags: python, python-import

How do I set up module imports so that each module can access the objects of all the others?

I have a medium size Python application with modules files in various subdirectories.  I have created modules that append these subdirectories to `sys.path` and imports a group of modules, using `import thisModule as tm`.  Module objects are referred to with that qualification.  I then import that module into the others with `from moduleImports import *`.  The code is sloppy right now and has several of these things, which are often duplicative.

First, the application is failing because some module references aren't assigned.  This same code does run when unit tested.

Second, I'm worried that I'm causing a problem with recursive module imports.  Importing moduleImports imports thisModule, which imports moduleImports . . . .

What is the right way to do this?

Comment: Don't know if this directly answers your question, but [I asked about importing a few days ago](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/860672/lay-out-import-pathing-in-python-straight-and-simple). Found the replies very helpful.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

**"I have a medium size Python application with modules files in various subdirectories."**

Good.  Make absolutely sure that each directory include a `__init__.py` file, so that it's a package.

**"I have created modules that append these subdirectories to `sys.path`"**

Bad.  Use `PYTHONPATH` or install the whole structure `Lib/site-packages`.   Don't update `sys.path` dynamically.  It's a bad thing.  Hard to manage and maintain.

**"imports a group of modules, using `import thisModule as tm`."**

Doesn't make sense.  Perhaps you have one `import thisModule as tm` for each module in your structure.  This is typical, standard practice: import just the modules you need, no others.

**"I then import that module into the others with `from moduleImports import *`"**

Bad.  Don't blanket import a bunch of random stuff.

Each module should have a longish list of the specific things it needs.

```
import this
import that
import package.module
```

Explicit list.  No magic.  No dynamic change to `sys.path`.

My current project has 100's of modules, a dozen or so packages.  Each module imports just what it needs.  No magic.

Comment: Wrapping in one sentence: "explicit is better than implicit."

Answer (score 6):

Few pointers

1. You may have already split
   functionality in various module. If
   correctly done most of the time you
   will not fall into circular import
   problems (e.g.  if module a depends
   on b and b on a you can make a third
   module c to remove such circular
   dependency). As last resort, in a
   import b but in b import a at the
   point where a is needed e.g. inside
   function.
2. Once functionality is properly in
   modules group them in packages under
   a subdir and add a `__init__.py` file
   to it so that you can import the
   package. Keep such pakages in a
   folder e.g. lib and then either add
   to sys.path or set PYTHONPATH env
   variable
3. from module import * may not
   be good idea. Instead, import whatever
   is needed. It may be fully qualified. It
   doesn't hurt to be verbose. e.g.
   from pakageA.moduleB import
   CoolClass.

Comment: Minor formatting note: I believe you mean __init__.py (use backticks around it to prevent it from being converted to bold.)

Comment: thanks, these simple formatting languages sometime becomes complex to manage

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "split functionality", or how a third module would help resolve interdependency among two modules.

Answer (score 4):

The way to do this is to avoid magic. In other words, if your module requires something from another module, it should import it explicitly. You shouldn't rely on things being imported automatically.

As the Zen of Python (`import this`) has it, explicit is better than implicit.

Answer (score 3):

You won't get recursion on imports because Python caches each module and won't reload one it already has.

Comment: circular import can really happen e.g. suppose b defines a function which a uses and both import each other see
http://www.copypastecode.com/codes/view/5193

Comment: @Anurag Uniyal: have you actually tested that? import keeps track of what it imports so there is no guarentee that even that code will cause recursive loading.

Comment: it does happen I don't remember the exact details now but it has something do with same module imported twice as main and then as module