# Importing modules in Python - best practice

Tags: python, coding-style, workflow, python-import

I am new to Python as I want to expand skills that I learned using R.
In R I tend to load a bunch of libraries, sometimes resulting in function name conflicts.

What is best practice in Python. I have seen some specific variations that I do not see a difference between

`import pandas`, `from pandas import *`, and  `from pandas import DataFrame`

What are the differences between the first two and should I just import what I need.
Also, what would be the worst consequences for someone making small programs to process data and compute simple statistics.

**UPDATE**

I found this [excellent guide](http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/writing/structure/#modules). It explains everything.

Comment: `import pandas` and `from pandas import DataFrame` both are okay. The second form `from pandas import *` is usually not to be recommended, because it pulls just everything into the global namespace.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Properly importing modules in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/896112/properly-importing-modules-in-python)

Answer (score 56, accepted):

`import pandas` imports the pandas module under the pandas namespace, so you would need to call objects within pandas using `pandas.foo`.

`from pandas import *` imports all objects from the pandas module into your current namespace, so you would call objects within pandas using only `foo`. Keep in mind this could have unexepcted consequences if there are any naming conflicts between your current namespace and the pandas namespace.

`from pandas import DataFrame` is the same as above, but only imports `DataFrame` (instead of everything) into your current namespace.

In my opinion the first is generally best practice, as it keeps the different modules nicely compartmentalized in your code.

Answer (score 85):

## Disadvantage of each form

When reading other people's code (and those people use very
different importing styles), I noticed the following problems with
each of the styles:

**`import modulewithaverylongname`** will clutter the code further down
with the long module name (e.g. `concurrent.futures` or `django.contrib.auth.backends`) and decrease readability in those places.

**`from module import *`** gives me no chance to see syntactically that,
for instance, `classA` and `classB` come from the same module and
have a lot to do with each other.
It makes reading the code *hard*.
(That names from such an import
may shadow names from an earlier import is the least part of that problem.)

**`from module import classA, classB, functionC, constantD, functionE`**
overloads my short-term memory with too many names
that I mentally need to assign to `module` in order to
coherently understand the code.

**`import modulewithaverylongname as mwvln`** is sometimes insufficiently
mnemonic to *me*.

## A suitable compromise

Based on the above observations, I have developed the following
style in my own code:

**`import module`** is the preferred style if the module name is short
as for example most of the packages in the standard library.
It is also the preferred style if I need to use names from the module in
only two or three places in my own module;
clarity trumps brevity then ([*"Readability counts"*](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/)).

**`import longername as ln`** is the preferred style in almost every
other case.
For instance, I might `import django.contrib.auth.backends as djcab`.
By definition of criterion 1 above, the abbreviation will be used
frequently and is therefore sufficiently easy to memorize.

Only these two styles are fully pythonic as per the
[*"Explicit is better than implicit."*](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/) rule.

**`from module import xx`** still occurs sometimes in my code.
I use it in cases where even the `as` format appears exaggerated,
the most famous example being `from datetime import datetime`
(but if I need more elements, I will `import datetime as dt`).

Comment: **Lovely piece, Lutz**. +1 for the profile **"Timeless Principles" motivation** - it is genuine & very important in the ages of creeping erosion of knowledge and moving sands we base our systems on.

Comment: I agree this is a suitable compromise. I use `from module import xx` only when importing a class of my own which is defined in another file.

Comment: It is so boring not to know from which package comes a given object. The  so-called *suitable compromise* is clearly the way to go if we want to build "sharable" and readable codes. Incidentally, it also prevents names conflicts. +1

Comment: Like you, I prefer importing the module, but when the module lies within a package, I sometimes use `from <package> import <module>`, especially when the module is several sub-packages deep. I'd much rather type `file_generators.Random()` than `libraries.file_utils.generators.file_generators.Random()`, so I would just use `from libraries.file_utils.generators import file_generators`.

Answer (score 31):

Here are some recommendations from [PEP8 Style Guide.](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/)

1. **Imports should usually be on separate lines**, e.g.:

   ```
   Yes: import os
        import sys

   No:  import sys, os
   ```

   but it is okay to

   ```
   from subprocess import Popen, PIPE
   ```
2. **Imports are always put at the top of the file, just after any module comments and docstrings, and before module globals and constants.**

   - Imports should be grouped in the following order:

     1. standard library imports
     2. related third party imports
     3. local application/library specific imports
   - You should put a blank line between each group of imports.
3. **Absolute imports are recommended** 
   They are more readable and make debugging easier by giving better error messages in case you mess up import system.

   ```
   import mypkg.sibling
   from mypkg import sibling
   from mypkg.sibling import example
   ```

   or **explicit relative imports**

   ```
   from . import sibling
   from .sibling import example
   ```
4. **Implicit relative imports should never be used** and is removed in Python 3.

   ```
   No:  from ..grand_parent_package import uncle_package
   ```
5. **Wildcard imports ( `from <module> import *` ) should be avoided**, as they make it unclear which names are present in the namespace, confusing both readers and many automated tools.

---

Some recommendations about `lazy imports` from [python speed performance tips.](https://wiki.python.org/moin/PythonSpeed/PerformanceTips#Import_Statement_Overhead)

> ### Import Statement Overhead
>
> import statements can be executed just about anywhere. It's often useful to place them inside functions to restrict their visibility and/or reduce initial startup time. Although Python's interpreter is optimized to not import the same module multiple times, repeatedly executing an import statement can seriously affect performance in some circumstances.

the given below is a scenario explained at the page,

```
>>> def doit1():
... import string
... string.lower('Python')
...
>>> import string
>>> def doit2():
... string.lower('Python')
...
>>> import timeit
>>> t = timeit.Timer(setup='from __main__ import doit1', stmt='doit1()')
>>> t.timeit()
11.479144930839539
>>> t = timeit.Timer(setup='from __main__ import doit2', stmt='doit2()')
>>> t.timeit()
4.6661689281463623
```

Comment: What is the difference between the implicit and explicit relative inputs ?

Answer (score 26):

In general it is better to do explicit imports.
As in:

```
import pandas
frame = pandas.DataFrame()
```

Or:

```
from pandas import DataFrame
frame = DataFrame()
```

Another option in Python, when you have conflicting names, is import x as y:

```
from pandas import DataFrame as PDataFrame
from bears import DataFrame as BDataFrame
frame1 = PDataFrame()
frame2 = BDataFrame()
```

Answer (score 8):

```
from A import B
```

essentially equals following three statements

```
import A
B = A.B
del A
```

That's it, that is it all.

Comment: This isn't entirely correct. `from A import B` will import `A` into the global namespace, and `B` as well.  You can still do `A.C` (or even `A.B` if you'd like), but you can also do `B` `from itertools import imap
>>> itertools
<module 'itertools' (built-in)>
>>> imap
itertools.imap
>>> itertools.starmap
itertools.starmap`

Comment: Thus there isn't anything like `del A`

Comment: @DanOberlam That may be out of date. In Python 3.8 I get a NameError when I try to access itertools in your example.

Answer (score 2):

They are all suitable in different contexts (which is why they are all available). There's no deep guiding principle, other than generic motherhood statements around clarity, maintainability and simplicity. Some examples from my own code:

1. `import sys, os, re, itertools` avoids name collisions and provides a very succinct way to import a bunch of standard modules.
2. `from math import *` lets me write `sin(x)` instead of `math.sin(x)` in math-heavy code. This gets a bit dicey when I also import numpy, which doubles up on some of these, but it doesn't overly concern me, since they are generally the same functions anyway. Also, I tend to follow the numpy documentation — `import numpy as np` — which sidesteps the issue entirely.
3. I favour `from PIL import Image, ImageDraw` just because that's the way the PIL documentation presents its examples.

Comment: If you want to do `sin(x)` instead of `math.sin(x)` why not use `from math import sin`?

Comment: @Chiggs: In math-oriented code, I rarely want just `sin`. If I want just a handful of symbols, I could import each one as a comma-list, but I usually can't be bothered figuring out which ones I'll need. `*` is convenient, if a bit lazy.

Comment: Those examples are all easy to write but not necessarily easy to read, and go against best practices.