# mixing up pygame.time() and time.time()

Tags: python, python-3.x, time, pygame

For a minesweeper game I am using `time.time()`, I have imported both `time` and `pygame`. Here is my error report

```
line 5, in save_score
    end = time.time()
AttributeError: module 'pygame.time' has no attribute 'time'
```

Here you have the proof that I did import both time and pygame:

```
import sys, math, time
def save_score(name, size, mine):
    end = time.time()
~
from pygame import *
```

If anyone can explain how to avoid/ fix this error, it'd be much appreciated.

Comment: You have a conflict when doing `from pygame import *` (check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9916878/importing-modules-in-python-best-practice)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're encountering a namespace collision, due to your line:

```
from pygame import *
```

This is polluting your global namespace with everything you can import from pygame.  It makes lazy life easy - you don't have to refer to the specific namespace to use pygame's functions.  But it has some bad consequences, too.

In this case, you had imported "time" as a module in the global namespace.  When you import as you did from pygame, it had a submodule called time.  pygame.time replace your regular time module.

The way to fix this is to use module/namespaces properly.

One way to do that, is instead of using `from pygame import *`, instead use:

```
import pygame
```

But then you have to put pygame in front of every reference to a pygame function or module.  This is generally good, that way you and anyone else who reads your code knows exactly what function you're calling.

You can abbreviate it a little bit, using `import ... as`:

```
import pygame as pg
```

Then instead of doing things like `pygame.time`, you would do `pg.time`.

If there are some things you want to specifically put into the global namespace, you can do things like:

```
from pygame import foo
```

or

```
from pygame import time as pygt
```

But if you do `from pygame import time` or `from pygame import *`, pygame's time will overwrite the other time module.