# Problem importing modules and functions in Python

Tags: python

I have two files: in one of them (named `myrandom`) I have defined a function called `spinner` that would choose a random number from 1 to 6 and would return its value. In the second file, named `main`, I have imported the first one (as a module) and have also called the `spinner` function.

This is the code of the file `myrandom`:

```
def spinner():
    import random
    val = random.choice([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6])
    return val
```

And this is the code of `main`:

```
import myrandom

x = spinner()
print(x)
```

My problem is that when I run `main`, I get the following error message: "NameError: name spinner() is not defined". I don't know why I'm getting this error, since I have other files and modules with similar characteristics that run without problems.

Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use it like:

```
import myrandom

x = myrandom.spinner()
```

Or import directly:

```
from myrandom import spinner
x = spinner()
```

Or use star import:

```
from myrandom import *
x = spinner()
```

Answer (score 0):

You should import it either like this:

```
import myrandom

x = myrandom.spinner()
```

or like this:

```
from myrandom import spinner

x = spinner()
```

or like this:

```
from myrandom import *

x = spinner()
```

An explanation of the different ways of importing can be found here: [Importing modules in Python - best practice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9916878/importing-modules-in-python-best-practice)