# Imports and name bindings best practice

Tags: python, class, import, module

This is closely related to: [Importing modules in Python - best practice](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9916878/1720199)
, but the following case is not really  discussed in details.

If we have a module `coordinates` that defines one class `Coordinates` and several utility function to work with the `Coordinates` type. What is the recommended way to do the following two things:

1. Import the complete `coordinates` module
2. While binding `Coordinates` to `coordinates.Coordinates`

The two options I see for now:

```py
import coordinates
from coordinates import Coordinates
```

But that seems a bit odd, on the other hand the other solution I see doesn't seem very clean either:

```py
import coordinates 
Coordinates = coordinates.Coordinates
```

Which one of this two is the most commonly used or the prefered way of doing this? Or maybe both of these shouldn't be used, in which case what would be a better solution?

Another option I'm considering but that I would prefer to avoid is one proposed in the referenced question: `import coordinates as crd` and then simply use `crd.Coordinates` instead of `Coordinates`. The reason why I want to avoid this is because it would make my code less readable, in particular when I use a function from the `coordinates` module. To this alternative I would probably prefer to simply call `coordinates.Coordinates` even if that looks redundant.

I've also considered [making my module callable](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1060872/1720199) to make `coordinates()` to automatically call `Coordinates()` but I'm not really sure it's really a good solution either (and I'm not sure how to handle the documentation in such case).

Comment: And you don't want to do `from coordinates import *`? As for your question I would go with the first option... It would make more sense to other developers

Comment: `Never` do star imports, unless you know what you are doing

Comment: No, for sure I don't want that, my linter wouldn't really like it :p

Answer (score 0):

It is a matter of personal preference, but for myself, I'd go with:

```
from coordinates import Coordinates
```

*Unless*, that is, you are using more than, oh, three or four things from the `coordinates` module, or one of the names you are importing from it clashs with names you are using from elsewhere. In either of those cases, go with

```
import coordinates
```

Comment: The number of function from `coordinates` I'm using is (in some cases) greater than four. In these cases I don't really want to call `from coordinates import Coordinates, foo, bar, baz, etc`.  I would also like to be consistent on how I import my module/class within my project (once again, unless I have no other viable alternative).

Comment: Like I say, it's a matter of personal preference.