# Is it good or bad practice to reference a single library.py file with all imports?

Tags: python, django, import, libraries

I am making a Django project with multiple apps and was wondering if it would be considered good or bad practice to create a single library.py file with all the "import x" and "from x import y, z" statements and then simply put "from library.py import *" at the top of every other file?

What would be considered best practice for managing your imported libraries like this?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: You should **never** use `from X import *`. Imagine `X` exposing a function called `min` (or anything else that clashes with built-in names or even names defined in your importing script)

Answer (score 1):

From the [zen of Python](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/): 'Explicit is better than implicit'. So it would be better to explicitly import everything. This makes debugging for example more clear.

See for more details about importing the discussion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9916878/importing-modules-in-python-best-practice)