# how to access attributes initialized in class constructor of different py file?

Tags: python, oop

I have two py files. a.py and b.py inside a package called test (has `__init__.py`)

and I want to access attribute self.items defined in the a.py below

```
import b

class Window(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.items={'Magenta':'mag','Grey':'gre','Red':'red'}
    def getMats():
        newobj=b.BAR()
        selected = newobj.type_of_mats[1]
```

from a different py file b.py[below] so in b.py I imported the a module i.e.

```
import a

#now 

obj = a.Window()
print obj.items['Magenta']
class BAR(object):
    def myMat(self):
        type_of_mats=['ground', 'corridor', 'Outdoor']
```

should'nt the above prints mag since or how else I should do it ?

Comment: Yes, it should. What happens when you try?

Comment: @Marthin : how did u updated instantly i pressed save ?

Comment: @DanielRoseman : I get error saying maximum recursion depth exceded in cmp in ntpath.py, I am on python 2.6,

I also need to access attributes from b.py to be read by a.py ,
so in a.py I have import b

Comment: Then you have some other code you're not showing us. Please post some code that actually shows the problem, along with the full traceback.

Comment: ok wait i am updating I thought its not important..

Comment: @san: I was looking at the python question list; it was updated when you pressed save, saw the common error and made the edit.

Comment: @Martijin: but that was so quick, when i was going to fix u already did it ahead of me

Comment: @san it obviously *is* important, as your update has now revealed the problem, which was not evident before.

Comment: i do not get error if I do not initialize the object? i.e. newobj=b.Bar().. 

how can I use getAttr to get the attribute ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

see these stackoverflow questions on circular imports [(a)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/896112/properly-importing-modules-in-python) and [(b)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/744373/circular-or-cyclic-imports-in-python). I think it depends on the compiler / interpreter being used. In my case your code does not give me recursion depth exceeded, but [this does](http://www.copypastecode.com/5193/)

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Circular import. `a.py` imports `b` and `b.py` imports `a` again. Chicken/egg problem! And python cannot solve that for you, so it warns you about a maximum recursion depth (it keeps on jumping from a to b to a to b to a...).

You'll have to fix it so that the import is one-way only.

Answer (score 0):

You have a circular dependency: `a` is importing `b`, which is in turn importing `a`. Since those two imports are at module level, they can never complete.

In your case, you could fix it by moving the `import b` into the `getMats` method.