# Understanding python imports

Tags: python, django, import

In the process of learning Django and Python.  I can't make sense of this.

(Example Notes:'helloworld' is the name of my project.  It has 1 app called 'app'.)

```
from helloworld.views import *          # <<-- this works
from helloworld import views            # <<-- this doesn't work
from helloworld.app import views        # <<-- but this works.  why?
```

It seems like line #2 and #3 are practically the same.  Why does like #2 not work?

**Edit -- Added the source of the two files.**
You might recognize this code from the Django Book project ([http://www.djangobook.com/en/2.0](http://www.djangobook.com/en/2.0/))

### helloworld/views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response
from django.http import HttpResponse, Http404
import datetime

def hello(request):
    return HttpResponse("Hello world")


def current_datetime(request):
    current_date = datetime.datetime.now()
    return render_to_response('current_datetime.html', locals())


def offset_datetime(request, offset):
    try:
        offset = int(offset)
    except ValueError:
        raise Http404()

    next_time = datetime.datetime.now() + datetime.timedelta(hours=offset)
    return render_to_response('offset_datetime.html', locals())

def display_meta(request):
    values = request.META.items()
    values.sort()
    path = request.path
    return render_to_response('metavalues.html', locals())
```

### helloworld/app/views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response

def search_form(request):
    return render_to_response('search_form.html')

def search(request):
    if 'q' in request.GET:
        message = 'You searched for: %r' % request.GET['q']
    else:
        message = 'You searched for nothing.'

    return render_to_response('search_results.html', locals())
```

Comment: Post actual source of helloworld?

Comment: does 

    import helloworld.views as views

work?

Comment: do you have a file helloworld/__init__.py ?

Comment: yes, there's helloworld/__init__.py

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Python imports can import two different kinds of things: modules and objects.

```
import x
```

Imports an entire module named `x`.

```
import x.y
```

Imports a module named `y` and it's container `x`.  You refer to `x.y`.

When you created it, however, you created this directory structure

```
x
    __init__.py
    y.py
```

When you add to the import statement, you identify specific objects to pull from the module and move into the global namespace

```
import x # the module as a whole
x.a # Must pick items out of the module
x.b

from x import a, b # two things lifted out of the module
a # items are global
b
```

If helloworld is a package (a directory, with an `__init__.py` file), it typically doesn't contain any objects.

```
from x import y # isn't sensible
import x.y # importing a whole module.
```

Sometimes, you will have objects defined in the `__init__.py` file.

Generally, use "from module import x" to pick specific objects out of a module.

Use `import module` to import an entire module.

Comment: So "from helloworld import views" would better be written as, "import helloworld.views" ?  Did I understand that?

Comment: @T. Stone: Correct.  The standard library example is `import os.path`.

Answer (score 4):

```
from helloworld.views import *          # <<-- this works
from helloworld import views            # <<-- this doesn't work
from helloworld.app import views        # <<-- but this works.  why?
```

#2 and #3 are *not* the same.

The second one imports `views` from the package `helloworld`. The third one imports `views` from the package `helloworld.app`, which is a subpackage of `helloworld`. What it means is that views are specific to your django apps, and not your projects. If you had separate apps, how would you import views from each one? You have to specify the name of the app you want to import from, hence the syntax `helloworld.app`.

Answer (score 1):

As sykora alluded, helloworld is not in-and-of-itself a package, so #2 won't work.  You would need a helloworld.py, appropriately set up.

I asked about import a couple of days ago, this might help:
[Lay out import pathing in Python, straight and simple?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/860672/lay-out-import-pathing-in-python-straight-and-simple)