# What exactly does "import *" import?

Tags: python, namespaces, python-import

In Python, what exactly does `import *` import? Does it import `__init__.py` found in the containing folder?

For example, is it necessary to declare `from project.model import __init__`, or is `from project.model import *` sufficient?

Comment: `from yadda.yadda import *` is most useful when hacking at things in the Python command line, e.g. when you're using Python as a calculator and you just type out `from math import *`.  In a module, it's asking for trouble.  Also, if you import a single-file module (as opposed to a directory), `from ... import *` won't import symbols whose names begin with `_`.

Comment: Related: *[How does Java import work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12620369/how-does-java-import-work)*.

Answer (score 77, accepted):

The "advantage" of `from xyz import *` as opposed to other forms of import is that it imports *everything* (well, almost... [see (a) below] everything) from the designated module under the current module.  This allows using the various objects (variables, classes, methods...) from the imported module **without prefixing them with the module's name**.  For example

```
>>> from math import *
>>>pi
3.141592653589793
>>>sin(pi/2)
>>>1.0
```

**This practice (of importing * into the current namespace) is however discouraged** because it

- provides the opportunity for namespace collisions  (say if you had a variable name pi prior to the import)
- may be inefficient, if the number of objects imported is big
- doesn't explicitly document the origin of the variable/method/class  (it is nice to have this "self documentation" of the program for future visit into the code)

Typically we therefore limit this import * practice to ad-hoc tests and the like.  As pointed out by @Denilson-Sá-Maia, some libraries such as (e.g. pygame) have a sub-module where all the most commonly used constants and functions are defined and such sub-modules are effectively *designed* to be imported with `import *`.  Other than with these special sub-modules, it is otherwise preferable to ...:

**explicitly import a few objects only**

```
>>>from math import pi
>>>pi
>>>3.141592653589793
>>> sin(pi/2)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'sin' is not defined
```

or **import the module under its own namespace** (or an alias thereof, in particular if this is a long name, and the program references its objects many times)

```
  >>>import math
  >>>math.pi
  >>>3.141592653589793
  etc..


  >>>import math as m  #bad example math being so short and standard...
  >>>m.pi
  >>>3.141592653589793
  etc..
```

See the [**Python documentation on this topic**](http://docs.python.org/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-import-statement)

**(a) Specifically, what gets imported with `from xyz import *` ?** 
  if xyz module defines an `__all__` variable, it will import all the names defined in this sequence, otherwise it will import all names, except these which start with an underscore.

**Note** Many libraries have ***sub-modules***.  For example the standard library `urllib` includes sub-modules like `urllib.request`, `urllib.errors`, `urllib.response` etc.  A common point of confusion is that

`from urllib import *`

would import all these sub-modules. **That is NOT the case**: one needs to explicitly imports these separately with, say, `from urllib.request import *` etc.  This incidentally is not specific to `import *`,  plain `import` will not import sub-modules either (but of course, the `*` which is often a shorthand for *"everything"* may mislead people in thinking that all sub-modules and everything else would be imported).

Comment: The advantage of `from X import *` is that it allows you to be lazy. The problem of it is that it will bite you in the ass for lazy :)

Comment: Some modules (like [`pygame`](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/locals.html), but many others) have a special submodule that is intended to be imported as `*`. Such special modules usually have commonly used constants or functions.

Comment: So basically I can import everything without getting a name space collision if i use `import math` as opposed to `from math import*` ?

Comment: @the_prole Indeed.  `import math` ensures that there would be no name conflicts; to access any method or object from math in the code you will however need to prefix it with `math.`  as in `math.pi` or `math.sin(...)`.   With the `from math import *` there will be no need for the `math.` prefix (in fact that would work) but on the other there may be namespace collisions.

Comment: This answer is incomplete/incorrect/misleading. `import *` does not import submodules, which is often the cause of confusion. For example, after `from tkinter import *` you still have to do `from tkinter import messagebox` because `messagebox` is a submodule of tkinter.

Comment: @Aran-Fey Thank you for the feedback.  I added a note to dispel this common misconception.  Incidentally this behavior [of not loading/importing] the sub-modules is not specific to `import *` but indeed this is where it may be expected because of the usual meaning ascribed  to `*`.

Comment: Well, it's a bit more complicated than that. `import *` won't automatically load submodules that haven't been loaded yet, unless those submodules are listed in `__all__`, but it will import any submodules that happen to have already been loaded (usually due to other imports loading them). This can cause really weird bugs where the behavior of `import *` depends on import ordering and what code paths have been taken so far.

Answer (score 15):

It import (into the current namespace) whatever names the module (or package) lists in its `__all__` attribute -- missing such an attribute, all names that don't start with `_`.

It's mostly intended as a handy shortcut for use only in interactive interpreter sessions: as other answers suggest, **don't** use it in a program.

My recommendation, per [Google's Python style guide](https://google.github.io/styleguide/pyguide.html), is to only ever import *modules*, **not** classes or functions (or other names) from within modules.  Strictly following this makes for clarity and precision, and avoids subtle traps that may come when you import "stuff from within a module".

Importing a package (or anything from inside it) intrinsically loads and executes the package's `__init__.py` -- that file defines the body of the package.  However, it does not bind the name `__init__` in your current namespace (so in this sense it doesn't import that name).

Comment: So basically I can import everything without getting a name space collision if i use `import math` as opposed to `from math import*` ?

Answer (score 6):

Here is a nice way to see what star / asterisk ( * ) has imported from a module:

```
before = dir()
from math import *
after = dir()
print(set(after) - set(before))
```

returns:

```
{'modf', 'pow', 'erfc', 'copysign', 'sqrt', 'atan2', 'e', 'tanh', 'pi', 'factorial', 'cosh', 'expm1', 'cos', 'fmod', 'frexp', 'log', 'acosh', 'sinh', 'floor', 'isclose', 'lgamma', 'ceil', 'gcd', 'ldexp', 'hypot', 'radians', 'atan', 'isnan', 'atanh', 'before', 'isinf', 'fabs', 'isfinite', 'log10', 'nan', 'tau', 'acos', 'gamma', 'asin', 'log2', 'tan', 'degrees', 'asinh', 'erf', 'fsum', 'inf', 'exp', 'sin', 'trunc', 'log1p'}
```

I was working with my own module, importing everything explicitly but the list of stuff to import was getting too long. So, had to use this method to get a list of what * had imported.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, it does. It imports *everything* (that is not a private variable, i.e.: variables whose names start with `_` or `__`), and you should try not to use it according to "[Properly importing modules in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/896112/properly-importing-modules-in-python)" to avoid polluting the local namespace.

It is enough, but generally you should either do `import project.model`, which already imports `__init__.py`, per "[Understanding python imports](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/900591/understanding-python-imports)", but can get too wordy if you use it too much, or `import project.model as pm` or `import project.model as model` to save a few keystrokes later on when you use it.

Follow Alex's advice in "[What exactly does "import *" import?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2360724/in-python-what-exactly-does-import-import/2360782#2360782)"

Comment: Good recommendation, but imprecise information: `from foo import *` does **not** "import everything" -- it imports names listed in the module's `__all__` attribute, or, missing that attribute, _non-private_ names (excluding names starting with `_`).

Comment: @Alex, good point. Would you like to expand on it, or would you prefer that I do it?

Comment: I've already expanded on it -- see my answer to this question.

Answer (score 4):

If `project.model` is a package, the module referred to by `import project.model` is from `.../project/model/__init__.py`. `from project.model import *` dumps everything from `__init__.py`'s namespace into yours. It does not automatically do anything with the other modules in model. The preferred style is for `__init__.py` not to contain anything.

Never ever ever ever ever use `import *`. It makes your code unreadable and unmaintainable.

Answer (score 2):

If the module in question (`project.model` in your case) has defined a list of stings named `__all__`, then every named variable in that list is imported. If there is no such variable, it imports everything.