# Why is "import *" bad?

Tags: python, python-import

It is recommended to not to use `import *` in Python.

Can anyone please share the reason for that, so that I can avoid it doing next time?

Comment: it depends if you are scripting or writing code you need to reuse. it sometimes pays to ignore code standards. "import *" can also be fine if you have a naming convention that makes it clear where stuff came from. e.g. "from Cats import *; TabbyCat; MaineCoonCat; CalicoCat;"

Comment: `import *` doesn't work for me in the first place in Python 2 or 3.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What exactly does "import \*" import?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2360724/what-exactly-does-import-import)

Comment: A more subtle version is the `using package.module;` from C#, although it usually has one or two more safeguards when compiling.

Answer (score 271, accepted):

- Because it puts a lot of stuff into your namespace (might shadow some other object from previous import and you won't know about it).
- Because you don't know exactly what is imported and can't easily find from which module a certain thing was imported (readability).
- Because you can't use cool tools like `pyflakes` to statically detect errors in your code.

Comment: Yeah, I really hate at my job when someone uses * import, because then I can't just run pyflakes and be happy, but have to repair those imports. It's nice though, that with that pyflakes helps me to :-)

Comment: As a concrete example, many users of NumPy have been bitten by `numpy.any` shadowing `any` when they do `from numpy import *` or a "helpful" tool does it for them.

Comment: Should I avoid using the --pylab switch for IPython for the same reasons?

Comment: To highlight a risk I'd never thought of before reading this ("might shadow some other object from previous import"): `import *` makes the _order_ of the `import` statements significant... even for standard library modules that don't normally care about import order.  Something as innocent as alphabetizing your `import` statements could break your script when a former casualty of the import war becomes the sole survivor.  (Even if your script works now and never changes, it could suddenly fail sometime later if the imported module introduces a new name that replaces one you were relying on.)

Comment: I actually came here wondering why all the GIS reference code I see (and many others, even tutorials), people "import <library>" and then import just the sub-module they want to use "from <library> import <redundancy>", they never use <library>.<whatever> and then they use the submodule directly. I see this everywhere, do people just not know how Python imports work?

Answer (score 64):

According to the [Zen of Python](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/):

> Explicit is better than implicit.

... can't argue with that, surely?

Comment: The only argument is that Python supports "import *" - if the consensus is that it is bad, then the feature should be removed, perhaps in Python 4 when people are expecting pain, anyway.

Comment: @user3481644 Some usecases allow you to disregard common good practices of software engineering to gain productivity. Think of short-lived semi-interactive data-visualization-scripts.

Comment: @julaine Yeah, I agree with the "quick and dirty" concept and as much as I want to argue against it, I cannot because I do like "import \*". Perhaps a compromise would be what Eclipse does with "import \*" (equivalent) for Java - it examines what is included and expands the '*' to explicit imports. A handy tool for Python would be a compile type option, --expand-import-star, that would instruct Python to report what import * actually needs and the programmer could copy-n-paste that back into the source file. That could be integrated into an IDE, too.

Answer (score 44):

You don't pass `**locals()` to functions, do you?

Since Python lacks an "include" statement, *and* the `self` parameter is explicit, *and* scoping rules are quite simple, it's usually very easy to point a finger at a variable and tell where that object comes from -- without reading other modules and without any kind of IDE (which are limited in the way of introspection anyway, by the fact the language is very dynamic).

The `import *` breaks all that.

Also, it has a concrete possibility of hiding bugs.

```
import os, sys, foo, sqlalchemy, mystuff
from bar import *
```

Now, if the bar module has any of the "`os`", "`mystuff`", etc... attributes, they will override the explicitly imported ones, and possibly point to very different things. Defining `__all__` in bar is often wise -- this states what will implicitly be imported - but still it's hard to trace where objects come from, without reading and parsing the bar module and following *its* imports. A network of `import *` is the first thing I fix when I take ownership of a project.

Don't misunderstand me: if the `import *` were missing, I would cry to have it. But it has to be used carefully. A good use case is to provide a facade interface over another module.
Likewise, the use of conditional import statements, or imports inside function/class namespaces, requires a bit of discipline.

I think in medium-to-big projects, or small ones with several contributors, a minimum of hygiene is needed in terms of statical analysis -- running at least pyflakes or even better a properly configured pylint -- to catch several kind of bugs before they happen.

Of course since this is python -- feel free to break rules, and to explore -- but be wary of projects that could grow tenfold, if the source code is missing discipline it will be a problem.

Comment: Python 2.x *does* have an "include" statement.  It's called `execfile()`.  Luckily, it's rarely used and gone in 3.x.

Comment: How about `**vars()` to include globals if the called function is in another file? :P

Answer (score 24):

That is because you are polluting the namespace. You will import all the functions and classes in your own namespace, which may clash with the functions you define yourself.

Furthermore, I think using a qualified name is more clear for the maintenance task; you see on the code line itself where a function comes from, so you can check out the docs much more easily.

In module foo:

```
def myFunc():
    print 1
```

In your code:

```
from foo import *

def doThis():
    myFunc() # Which myFunc is called?

def myFunc():
    print 2
```

Answer (score 21):

It is OK to do `from ... import *` in an interactive session.

Comment: How about inside a `doctest` string? Does the `import *` get interpreted inside a "sandbox" in this case? Thanks.

Answer (score 14):

Say you have the following code in a module called foo:

```
import ElementTree as etree
```

and then in your own module you have:

```
from lxml import etree
from foo import *
```

You now have a difficult-to-debug module that *looks like* it has lxml's etree in it, but really has ElementTree instead.

Comment: Indeed. Just ran across a problem where a bug was created by rearranging imports in the top-level module because star imports were used everywhere. Star imports create an order dependence for imports.

Answer (score 14):

Understood the valid points people put here. However, I do have one argument that, sometimes, "star import" may not always be a bad practice:

- When I want to structure my code in such a way that all the constants go to a module called `const.py`:

  - If I do `import const`, then for every constant, I have to refer it as `const.SOMETHING`, which is probably not the most convenient way.
  - If I do `from const import SOMETHING_A, SOMETHING_B ...`, then obviously it's way too verbose and defeats the purpose of the structuring.
  - Thus I feel in this case, doing a `from const import *` may be a better choice.

Comment: agree for this one. Especially by using capital letter will make it easier to understand that this variable is one of the constant defined in the const.py

Comment: This is the very thing `__all__` exists for, as it allows you to define what `from const import *` actually imports from the side of `const`. As a free bonus, it also helps you prevent accidentally importing things that were imported in `const.py` because they were needed there!

Answer (score 11):

http://docs.python.org/tutorial/modules.html

> Note that in general the practice of importing `*` from a module or package is frowned upon, since it often causes **poorly readable code**.

Answer (score 9):

These are all good answers. I'm going to add that when teaching new people to code in Python, dealing with `import *` is very difficult. Even if you or they didn't write the code, it's still a stumbling block.

I teach children (about 8 years old) to program in Python to manipulate Minecraft. I like to give them a helpful coding environment to work with ([Atom Editor](http://atom.io)) and teach REPL-driven development (via [bpython](http://bpython-interpreter.org/)). In Atom I find that the hints/completion works just as effectively as bpython. Luckily, unlike some other statistical analysis tools, Atom is not fooled by `import *`.

However, lets take this example... In [this wrapper](https://github.com/arpruss/raspberryjammod/blob/74e8738f5d607d7417e0bb5feaeb9a22b098ca42/python3-scripts/mcpipy/mc.py) they `from local_module import *` a bunch modules including [this list of blocks](https://github.com/arpruss/raspberryjammod/blob/74e8738f5d607d7417e0bb5feaeb9a22b098ca42/python3-scripts/mcpipy/mcpi/block.py#L112-L119). Let's ignore the risk of namespace collisions. By doing `from mcpi.block import *` they make this entire list of obscure types of blocks something that you have to go look at to know what is available. If they had instead used `from mcpi import block`, then you could type `walls = block.` and then an autocomplete list would pop up.
[image: Atom.io screenshot]

Answer (score 8):

It is a **very BAD** practice for two reasons:

1. Code Readability
2. Risk of overriding the variables/functions etc

---

For **point 1**:
Let's see an example of this:

```
from module1 import *
from module2 import *
from module3 import *

a = b + c - d
```

Here, on seeing the code no one will get idea regarding from which module `b`, `c` and `d` actually belongs.

On the other way, if you do it like:

```
#                   v  v  will know that these are from module1
from module1 import b, c   # way 1
import module2             # way 2

a = b + c - module2.d
#            ^ will know it is from module2
```

It is much cleaner for you, and also the new person joining your team will have better idea.

For **point 2**: Let say both `module1` and `module2` have variable as `b`. When I do:

```
from module1 import *
from module2 import *

print b  # will print the value from module2
```

Here the value from `module1` is lost. It will be hard to debug why the code is not working even if `b` is declared in `module1` and I have written the code expecting my code to use `module1.b`

If you have same variables in different modules, and you do not want to import entire module, you may even do:

```
from module1 import b as mod1b
from module2 import b as mod2b
```

Answer (score 3):

As suggested in the docs, you should (almost) never use `import *` in production code.

While importing `*` from a *module* is bad, [importing * from a *package*](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html#importing-from-a-package) is probably even worse.

By default, `from package import *` imports whatever names are defined  by the package's `__init__.py`, including any submodules of the package that were **loaded by previous `import` statements**.

If a package’s `__init__.py` code defines a list named `__all__`, it is taken to be the list of *submodule names* that should be imported when `from package import *` is encountered.

Now consider this example (assuming there's no `__all__` defined in `sound/effects/__init__.py`):

```
# anywhere in the code before import *
import sound.effects.echo
import sound.effects.surround

# in your module
from sound.effects import *
```

The last statement will import the `echo` and `surround` modules into the current namespace (possibly overriding previous definitions) because they are defined in the `sound.effects` package when the `import` statement is executed.

Answer (score 2):

As a test, I created a module test.py with 2 functions A and B, which respectively print "A 1" and "B 1". After importing test.py with:

```
import test
```

. . . I can run the 2 functions as test.A() and test.B(), and "test" shows up as a **module** in the namespace, so if I edit test.py I can reload it with:

```
import importlib
importlib.reload(test)
```

But if I do the following:

```
from test import *
```

there is no reference to "test" in the namespace, so there is no way to reload it after an edit (as far as I can tell), which is a problem in an interactive session. Whereas either of the following:

```
import test
import test as tt
```

will add "test" or "tt" (respectively) as module names in the namespace, which will allow re-loading.

If I do:

```
from test import *
```

the names "A" and "B" show up in the namespace as **functions**. If I edit test.py, and repeat the above command, the modified versions of the functions do not get reloaded.

And the following command elicits an error message.

```
importlib.reload(test)    # Error - name 'test' is not defined
```

If someone knows how to reload a module loaded with "from module import *", please post. Otherwise, this would be another reason to avoid the form:

```
from module import *
```