# TypeError: module.__init__() takes at most 2 arguments (3 given)

Tags: python, python-3.x, inheritance, typeerror

I have defined a class in a file named `Object.py`. When I try to inherit from this class in another file, calling the constructor throws an exception:

```
TypeError: module.__init__() takes at most 2 arguments (3 given)
```

This is my code:

```
import Object

class Visitor(Object):
    pass

instance = Visitor()  # this line throws the exception
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Could you please select the answer provided? It appears to be correct and will allow other questions to be closed as dupes of yours.

Comment: Hey @wakamdr the duplicate question functionality is pretty useful. Is there a reason why my answer is not correct?

Comment: An answer doesn't need to be accepted for other questions to be dupe-closed as duplicates of this one.

Answer (score 324):

Your error is happening because `Object` is a module, not a class. So your inheritance is screwy.

Change your import statement to:

```
from Object import ClassName
```

and your class definition to:

```
class Visitor(ClassName):
```

**or**

change your class definition to:

```
class Visitor(Object.ClassName):
   etc
```

Comment: Wiil it work the same, if one omit `ClassName` completely? Like `class Visitor()`?

Comment: @VMAtm: Why dont you try it and find out. Python's great cos it has the interpreter. Great for quick experimentation

Comment: Genius. worst error line in the world. took me 3 hours to figure out i was using the module and not the class. #$%^$%&$%&

Comment: To make this more clear for Java users, the file is Object and the class is ClassName. In Python a file is a module and the class definition(s) inside the file are the classes.

Comment: This solved my drama ! I usually import classes like this: from app.folder.file import class_name and I wrote: from app.folder . so it was not working (folder is a python package, so it has the __init__.py inside.)

Answer (score 18):

Even after @Mickey Perlstein's answer and his 3 hours of detective work, it still took me a few more minutes to apply this to my own mess. In case anyone else is like me and needs a little more help, here's what was going on in my situation.

- responses is a module
- Response is a base class within the responses module
- GeoJsonResponse is a new class derived from Response

Initial GeoJsonResponse class:

```
from pyexample.responses import Response

class GeoJsonResponse(Response):

    def __init__(self, geo_json_data):
```

Looks fine. No problems until you try to debug the thing, which is when you get a bunch of seemingly vague error messages like this:

> from pyexample.responses import GeoJsonResponse
>   ..\pyexample\responses\GeoJsonResponse.py:12: in (module)
>      class GeoJsonResponse(Response):
>
> E   TypeError: module() takes at most 2 arguments (3 given)
>
> =================================== ERRORS ====================================
>
> ___________________ ERROR collecting tests/test_geojson.py ____________________
>
> test_geojson.py:2: in (module)
>       from pyexample.responses import GeoJsonResponse ..\pyexample\responses \GeoJsonResponse.py:12: in (module)
>
> class GeoJsonResponse(Response): 
>   E   TypeError: module() takes at most 2 arguments (3 given)
>
> ERROR: not found: \PyExample\tests\test_geojson.py::TestGeoJson::test_api_response
>
> C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\aenum__init__.py:163
>
> (no name 'PyExample\ tests\test_geojson.py::TestGeoJson::test_api_response' in any of [])

The errors were doing their best to point me in the right direction, and @Mickey Perlstein's answer was dead on, it just took me a minute to put it all together in my own context:

I was importing the ***module***:

```
from pyexample.responses import Response
```

when I should have been importing the ***class***:

```
from pyexample.responses.Response import Response
```

Hope this helps someone. (In my defense, it's still pretty early.)

Comment: how is this related to the question?

Answer (score 8):

```
from Object import Object
```

or

```
From Class_Name import Class_name
```

If Object is a `.py` file.

Answer (score 4):

### Modules vs classes with basic `import` syntax

Errors like this most commonly happen because programmers expect Python to work like Java - where source files are expected to include exactly one "public" class named after the file, and `import` provides access to the class.

Python is not Java. Python does not have access modifier keywords; it allows putting any number of classes (including zero) in a source file; it also allows for things other than classes at the top level of the code; and it **does not have any special behaviour** for classes that share a name with the source file.

Code like `import Object` (assuming that the import succeeds) means that `Object` will be the name of a **module, not a class**. Python will not give special treatment to any class here **even if** it has the same name as the module. A hypothetical class `Object` defined within `Object.py` will be the `Object` **attribute of** the `Object` module: `Object.Object`.

Modules are not classes, and are thus not suitable as base classes.

Supposing that the `Object` module defines an `Object` class, to use that as a base class, choose one:

- refer to it by that qualified name:

  ```
  import Object

  class Visitor(Object.Object):
      pass
  ```
- explicitly alias it:

  ```
  import Object

  my_object = Object.Object
  class Visitor(my_object):
      pass
  ```
- use `from ... import` syntax to assign the class directly to the desired name:

  ```
  from Object import Object

  class Visitor(Object):
      pass
  ```

  or, alias it as well, using `as`:

  ```
  from Object import Object as my_object

  class Visitor(my_object):
      pass
  ```

**However, be careful** with the latter syntax:

### `from ... import` syntax

For imports that look like `from x.y import z`, there are two possibilities:

- `x` is a package, `y` is a module within that package, and `z` is some attribute of that module (again, classes are **not special**; `z` could be anything, such as an integer) - i.e., a global variable left over from running the code at the top level of the module.
- `x` is a package, `y` is a sub-package of that package, and `z` is a module in that sub-package.

(Python represents packages as a kind of module, so there is really only one distinction: whether the thing being `import`ed `from` the specified package/module is also a module, or some component thereof.)

Which result occurs, of course, **depends on what the `x` package's contents are**, which in turn could depend on *where* `x` was found. Having packages, subpackages, modules and attributes that reuse a common name, greatly increases the potential for confusion. (Unfortunately, the Python standard library does this in a couple of places, notably [with datetime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19480028)).

For example, given `x.py` and `y.py` in the same directory, where `x.py` implements a `x` class, one might write `from x import x` in the `y.py` code, expecting this to mean the class. However, if this "same directory" happens to be named `x`, and if *the parent directory* is the path that gets searched for an absolute import, then `from x import x` would mean the *module* (created from the `x.py` source file, imported `from` the package representing the `x` folder).

[As long as the package root is on the module search path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11536764/), the problem is easily avoided by using relative imports. Continuing the example, in `y.py`, `from .x import x` unambiguously means the class, and `from . import x` unambiguously means the sibling module. We don't need to reason about the contents of `sys.path`, or about what the current working directory will be at the time the `import` runs (in case `sys.path` includes a relative path), when writing the code; we only need to ensure that the code is run properly (such that the `y` module gets its `__package__` set properly).

### Why this specific error message?

I want to add some detail to the claim "So your inheritance is screwy".

The problem occurs because the code attempts to use something as a base class that isn't a type. Recall that in Python, classes are themselves objects, and that every object has some type (i.e., the class of which it is an instance).

When Python processes a call to a normal `class` definition, it will gather the contents and make a call to the built-in `type` (not a function, but a call to the constructor of the `type` class, which is the class that defines the default type of classes - including itself). That will be passed three arguments: the name of the class, as a string (here, `'Visitor'`), a tuple of the base classes for the new class (here, `(Object,)` - i.e., the module, by itself, in a tuple), and a dictionary of attributes to set for the new class (that will include all the methods and class variables defined inside the class body, plus some special things like `'__module__'` and `'__qualname__'`).

However, **the call to `type` isn't hard-coded**. Instead, Python looks for the type *of the bases*, in order to figure out what metaclass to use (`type` is only one possible metaclass). By doing this, Python ensures that derived classes have the same metaclass as the base class.

When the example code runs, Python will look up the type of `Object`, and find that it is a module. Therefore, instead of trying to create a new type, named `Visitor`, with `Object` as its base, it will try to create a new *module*, using the constructor for the `module` type (not assigned as a builtin by default).

As it happens, that constructor isn't documented (module objects are only supposed to be created by the `import` system, not directly by the user), but it takes either one or two arguments: the name of the new module (as a string), and optionally a value to use for the docstring (the module's `__doc__` attribute) - which incidentally is not type-checked; it is supposed to be either a string or `None`, but:

```
>>> import sys
>>> module = type(sys) # expose the type name
>>> example = module('example', [1, 2, 3])
>>> example.__doc__
[1, 2, 3]
```

(although it will be ignored by `help(example)` if it is not a string.)

Similarly, if we try to inherit from other things:

```
>>> class example(0): pass
... 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: int() takes at most 2 arguments (3 given)
>>> class example(()): pass
... 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: tuple expected at most 1 argument, got 3
```

If we try an object whose type *does* accept three arguments for its constructor, the failure is simply pushed back further:

```
>>> # 'example' is passed as a buffer to decode,
>>> # ('test',) is passed as an encoding,
>>> # and some dictionary is passed as the error-handling policy.
>>> # All of these values are clearly nonsensical.
>>> class example('test'): pass
... 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: str() argument 2 must be str, not tuple
```

Answer (score 3):

You may also do the following in Python 3.6.1

```
from Object import Object as Parent
```

and your class definition to:

```
class Visitor(Parent):
```

Answer (score -1):

In my case where I had the problem I was referring to a module when I tried extending the class.

```
import logging
class UserdefinedLogging(logging):
```

If you look at the Documentation Info, you'll see "logging" displayed as module.

In this specific case I had to simply inherit the logging module to create an extra class for the logging.