# AttributeError: 'datetime' module has no attribute 'strptime'

Tags: python, class, python-2.7

Here is my `Transaction` class:

```
class Transaction(object):
    def __init__(self, company, num, price, date, is_buy):
        self.company = company
        self.num = num
        self.price = price
        self.date = datetime.strptime(date, "%Y-%m-%d")
        self.is_buy = is_buy
```

And when I'm trying to run the `date` function:

```
tr = Transaction('AAPL', 600, '2013-10-25')
print tr.date
```

I'm getting the following error:

```
   self.date = datetime.strptime(self.d, "%Y-%m-%d")
 AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'strptime'
```

How can I fix that?

Comment: `from datetime import datetime`

Comment: I had the same issue today.  This is a known threading bug in Python 2 library.  It will not be fixed.  Solution: `import _strptime`
Read more here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32245560/module-object-has-no-attribute-strptime-with-several-threads-python/46401422

Shall we mark this as a dupe?

Answer (score 616, accepted):

If I had to guess, you did this:

```
import datetime
```

at the top of your code.  This means that you have to do this:

```
datetime.datetime.strptime(date, "%Y-%m-%d")
```

to access the `strptime` method.  Or, you could change the import statement to this:

```
from datetime import datetime
```

and access it as you are.

The people who made the [`datetime` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html) also named their [class `datetime`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#available-types):

```
#module  class    method
datetime.datetime.strptime(date, "%Y-%m-%d")
```

Comment: Reminds of the town Colombia in Colombia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Colombia,_Huila

Comment: Why is Python like this!? T__T

Comment: yeah. the irony of "wanting a beauty code" ruined by a silly syntax rule.

Comment: It's amazing to me that so many people are willing to complain that a module contains a class with the same name, and that using the functionality within the class means actually accessing the class first - but nobody seems to care that a Python standard library method is named with a garble of letters to match an ancient C function with an old-fashioned interface.

Answer (score 34):

Use the correct call: `strptime` is a classmethod of the `datetime.datetime` class, it's not a function in the `datetime` module.

```
self.date = datetime.datetime.strptime(self.d, "%Y-%m-%d")
```

---

As mentioned by Jon Clements in the comments, some people do `from datetime import datetime`, which would bind the `datetime` name to the `datetime` class, and make your initial code work.

To identify which case you're facing (in the future), look at your import statements

- `import datetime`: that's the module (that's what you have right now).
- `from datetime import datetime`: that's the class.

Comment: Sadly - if you're adapting someone else's code base - it's not uncommon for some to do `from datetime import datetime` and for other systems it's just a `import datetime` as it expects `datetime` to be a module... ;)

Answer (score 5):

I got the same problem and it is not the solution that you told. So I changed the "from datetime import datetime" to "import datetime". After that with 
 the help of "datetime.datetime" I can get the whole modules correctly. I guess this is the correct answer to that question.

Answer (score 4):

The solutions mentioned by the others are correct. But for me, it was a problem with another library importing datetime module for me and overriding the datetime class I was importing.
an example with [tsai](https://github.com/timeseriesAI/tsai/) library:

```
from datetime import datetime
from tsai.all import *
```

This will give you the error: `'module' object has no attribute 'strptime'`.

In this case, just flip the order of imports or just don't import everything (even if the documentation does that) :

```
from tsai.all import *
from datetime import datetime
```

Comment: I was importing an extra datetime in a pytest and didn't realize it. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Values ​​may differ depending on usage.

```
import datetime
date = datetime.datetime.now()
date.strftime('%Y-%m-%d') # date variable type is datetime
```

The value of the date variable must be a string::

```
date = '2021-09-06'
datetime.datetime.strptime(date, "%Y-%m-%d")
str(datetime.datetime.strptime(date, "%Y-%m-%d")) # show differently
```

Answer (score 1):

import datetime
self.date = datetime.datetime.strptime(date, "%Y-%m-%d")

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).