# how to check the minutes in python?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm working on my python script to check the minutes between the `00` and the `29` minutes.

When my local time is between 6:00PM and 6:29PM, I want to know how I can check the minutes of `00` and `29` in python?

Here is for example:

```
if (now.strftime("%d") >= "00" and <= "29")
   self.getControl(4203).setLabel(time.strftime("%I").lstrip('0') + ':00' + time.strftime("%p"))
else:
   self.getControl(4203).setLabel(time.strftime("%I").lstrip('0') + ':30' + time.strftime("%p"))
```

Comment: Question unclear, please rephrase.

Comment: Apparently he wants a function that takes a datetime and returns the two datetimes that are closest to it, that lie on the hour or half-hour. Ex. f(6:23) returns (6:00, 6:29), and f(3:47) returns (3:30, 3:59).

Comment: @Andy My question is when I have the local time is between 6:00PM and 6:30PM then do something. Please see my example code as you will get what I mean.

Comment: @Kevin yes you are correct. I need to create the if statement to check the time to see if i am on between 6:00PM annd 6:29PM or equal or after 6:30PM. I have no idea how to do that in python.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use [`datetime.datetime.now`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.now) to get the current time as a datetime object.  Then, you can access its [`minute`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.minute) attribute to get the minute as an integer:

```
>>> from datetime import datetime as dt
>>> dt.now()
datetime.datetime(2014, 7, 9, 13, 22, 49, 801000)
>>> dt.now().minute
22
>>> 0 <= dt.now().minute <= 29  # The minute is between 0 and 29 inclusive
True
>>>
```

Comment: @iCodez how do you write the code for if statement to check the minute is between 0 and 29? i tried this: `if (0 <= datetime.now().minute <= 29):`. I will get an error: `AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'now'`. Any idea?

Comment: `now` is an attribute of the `datetime` _class_, not the module.  You need to do `if (0 <= datetime.datetime.now().minute <= 29):`.  For more information, see my answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19480028/attributeerror-module-object-has-no-attribute-strptime-class/19480045#19480045).