# 'module' object has no attribute _strptime - python datetime

Tags: python, python-datetime

I developed a python script on osx which works with no problems.
On osx python version is 2.7.10.

Moving the same script on a raspberry pi3 with raspbian jessie and python 2.7.9 I obtained the error:

```
'module' object has no attribute '_strptime'
```

The interested module is datetime used in the following way:

```
...
    from datetime import datetime
...    
    millisecondsValue = datetime.strptime(ts, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
...
```

Thinking about the python version mismatch I tried to upgrade python using `apt-get install python2.7` but it says that it is already updated (clearly false). I have updated apt-get list also.
I have also tried to purge python2.7 and reinstall it but the version is still 2.7.9.
Moreover I installed python 3 hoping to run the script: no good news.

I've searched in stack overflow but the problems raised seems to be different compared by mine.
Is it possible that the python version is the problem?

Comment: Show a [mcve] and the complete stack trace.

Comment: Have you checked https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32245560/module-object-has-no-attribute-strptime-with-several-threads-python

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to do:

```
datetime.datetime.strptime(ts, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
```

to access the strptime method.