# Difference between two dates in Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python-2.7, pandas, dataframe, machine-learning

I have many columns in a data frame and I have to find the difference of time in two column named as `in_time` and `out_time` and put it in the new column in the same data frame.

The format of time is like this `2015-09-25T01:45:34.372Z`.

I am using Pandas DataFrame.

I want to do like this:

```
df.days = df.out_time - df.in_time
```

I have many columns and I have to increase 1 more column in it named days and put the differences there.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Calculate Pandas DataFrame Time Difference Between Two Columns in Hours and Minutes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22923775/calculate-pandas-dataframe-time-difference-between-two-columns-in-hours-and-minu)

Comment: My problem is different from yours ,I have many columns and I have to increase 1 more column in it named days and put the differences there.

Answer (score 9):

You need to convert the strings to `datetime` dtype, you can then subtract whatever arbitrary date you want and on the resulting series call `dt.days`:

```
In [15]:
df = pd.DataFrame({'date':['2015-09-25T01:45:34.372Z']})
df

Out[15]:
                       date
0  2015-09-25T01:45:34.372Z

In [19]:
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])
df['day'] = (df['date'] - dt.datetime.now()).dt.days
df

Out[19]:
                     date  day
0 2015-09-25 01:45:34.372 -252
```

Answer (score 4):

Well, it all kinda depends on the time format you use. I'd recommend using [datetime](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html).

If `in_time` and `out_time` are currently strings, convert them with `datetime.strptime()`:

```
from datetime import datetime

f = lambda x: datetime.strptime(x, '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%fZ')
df.in_time = df.in_time.apply(f)
df.out_time = df.out_time.apply(f)
```

and then you can simply subtract them, and assign the result to a new column named 'days':

```
df['days'] = df.out_time - df.in_time
```

**Example:** (3 seconds and 1 day differences)

```
In[5]: df = pd.DataFrame({'in_time':['2015-09-25T01:45:34.372Z','2015-09-25T01:45:34.372Z'],
                          'out_time':['2015-09-25T01:45:37.372Z','2015-09-26T01:45:34.372Z']})
In[6]: df
Out[6]: 
                    in_time                  out_time
0  2015-09-25T01:45:34.372Z  2015-09-25T01:45:37.372Z
1  2015-09-25T01:45:34.372Z  2015-09-26T01:45:34.372Z

In[7]: type(df.loc[0,'in_time'])
Out[7]: str

In[8]: df.in_time = df.in_time.apply(lambda x: datetime.strptime(x, '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%fZ'))   
In[9]: df.out_time = df.out_time.apply(lambda x: datetime.strptime(x, '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%fZ'))

In[10]: df    # notice that it looks exactly the same, but the type is different
Out[10]: 
                  in_time                  out_time
0 2015-09-25 01:45:34.372  2015-09-25T01:45:37.372Z
1 2015-09-25 01:45:34.372  2015-09-26T01:45:34.372Z

In[11]: type(df.loc[0,'in_time'])
Out[11]: pandas.tslib.Timestamp
```

And the creation of the new column:

```
In[12]: df['days'] = df.out_time - df.in_time
In[13]: df
Out[13]: 
                  in_time                out_time            days
0 2015-09-25 01:45:34.372 2015-09-25 01:45:37.372 0 days 00:00:03
1 2015-09-25 01:45:34.372 2015-09-26 01:45:34.372 1 days 00:00:00
```

Now you can play with the output format. For example, the portion of seconds difference:

```
In[14]: df.days = df.days.apply(lambda x: x.total_seconds()/60)
In[15]: df
Out[15]: 
                  in_time                out_time     days
0 2015-09-25 01:45:34.372 2015-09-25 01:45:37.372     0.05
1 2015-09-25 01:45:34.372 2015-09-26 01:45:34.372  1440.00
```

**Note:** Regarding the `in_time` and `out_time` format, notice that I made some assumptions (for example, that you're using a 24H clock (thus using `%H` and not `%I`)). To play with the format have a look at: [`strptime()` documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#strftime-strptime-behavior).

**Note2:** It would obviously be better if you can design your program to use `datetime` from the beginning (instead of using strings and converting them).

Comment: while using "f = lambda x: datetime.strptime(x, '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%fZ')
df.in_time = df.in_time.apply(f)"    giving error "'module' object has no attribute 'strptime'" ,how can I resolve this

Comment: 'strptime' is in datetime.datetime, not just datetime; see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19480028/attributeerror-module-object-has-no-attribute-strptime-class

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you need to convert in_time and out_time columns to `datetime` type.

```
for col in ('in_time', 'out_time') : # Looping a tuple is faster than a list
    df[col] = pd.to_datetime(df[col])
```

You can check the type using `dtypes`:

```
df['in_time'].dtypes
```

Should give: datetime64[ns, UTC]

Now you can substract them and get the difference time using `dt.days` or from `numpy` using `np.timedelta64`.

**Example:**

```
import numpy as np

df['days'] = (df['out_time'] - df['in_time']).dt.days 
# Or 
df['days'] = (df['out_time'] - df['in_time']) / np.timedelta64(1, 'D')
```