# How do I get the absolute difference between two datetime.time Pandas columns?

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, time, timedelta

Say I have this dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime

x = [datetime.time(23,0),datetime.time(6,0),datetime.time(18,0),datetime.time(17,0)]
y = [datetime.time(22,0),datetime.time(9,0),datetime.time(9,0),datetime.time(23,0)]

df = pd.DataFrame({'time1':x,'time2':y})
```

which looks like this:
[image]

How would I compute the absolute difference between the two columns? Subtraction doesn't work. The result should look like this:

```
df['abs_diff'] = [1,3,9,6]
```

[image]

Thanks so much!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Difference between two dates in Pandas DataFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37583870/difference-between-two-dates-in-pandas-dataframe)

Comment: the thing is that subtracting two times without a date is ambiguous and datetime.time doesn't support vectorization directly

Answer (score 3):

Pandas doesn't like `datetime` objects so very much; it labels the series as object dtype, so you can't really do any arithmetics on those. You can convert the data to Pandas' timedelta:

```
df['abs_diff'] = (pd.to_timedelta(df['time1'].astype(str))   # convert to timedelta
   .sub(pd.to_timedelta(df['time2'].astype(str)))            # then you can subtract
   .abs().div(pd.Timedelta('1H'))                            # and absolute value, and divide
)
```

Output:

```
      time1     time2  abs_diff
0  23:00:00  22:00:00       1.0
1  06:00:00  09:00:00       3.0
2  18:00:00  09:00:00       9.0
3  17:00:00  23:00:00       6.0
```

Comment: You couldn't do the arithmetic directly even if pandas liked the datetime.time - in vanilla Python you'd also use something different / convert types, like datetime.datetime or datetime.timedelta