# Converting a list into JSON with timestamp

Tags: python, json, pandas

I have a list of dictionaries like this:

```
  [{'accounts': [{'account_number': 'xx6747',
  'bank_name': 'Fargo Bank',
  'bankid': 85,
  'created_date_y': Timestamp('2015-05-20 08:08:33'),
  'item_account_id': 20086385.0,
  'item_id': 17764259,
  'user_id': 18},
  {'account_number': '*819',
 'bank_name': 'Central Alabama - Bank',
 'bankid': 88,
 'created_date_y': Timestamp('2015-05-20 08:08:33'),
 'item_account_id': 20637127.0,
 'item_id': 17761624,
 'user_id': 18},
 {'account_number': '*056',
'bank_name': 'Central Alabama - Bank',
'bankid': 88,
'created_date_y': Timestamp('2015-05-20 08:08:33'),
'item_account_id': 20087284.0,
'item_id': 17761624,
'user_id': 18},
'created_date_x': Timestamp('2014-03-11 10:48:42'),
'id': 18,
'password': 'NjgrUW9URGZz09',
'status': 1,
'uid': 97560,
'username': 'pepass@yahoo.com'},
{'accounts': [{'account_number': 791,
'bank_name': 'Chase - Bank',
'bankid': 855,
'created_date_y': Timestamp('2015-05-20 08:03:37'),
'item_account_id': 20090104.0,
'item_id': 17764260,
'user_id': 20},
{'account_number': 883,
'bank_name': 'Chase - Bank',
'bankid': 852,
'created_date_y': Timestamp('2015-05-20 08:03:37'),
'item_account_id': 20090105.0,
'item_id': 17764260,
'user_id': 20}],
'created_date_x': Timestamp('2014-03-11 13:42:20'),
'id': 20,
'password': 'bmJlbTN5dFo5QT09',
'status': 1,
'uid': 99408,
'username': 'hor@sanstore.com'}]
```

It contains other items as well. The `created_date_x` and `created_date_y` are timestamps. **I want to convert this list into a nested dictionary something like this:**

```
 {'id': 18,
  'password': 'NjgrUW9URGZz09',
  'status': 1,
  'uid': 97560,
  'username': 'pepass@yahoo.com'},
  'created_date_x': Timestamp('2014-03-11 10:48:42')
{'accounts': 
       [{'account_number': 'xx6747',
       'bank_name': 'Fargo Bank',
       'bankid': 85,
       'created_date_y': Timestamp('2015-05-20 08:08:33'),
       'item_account_id': 20086385.0,
       'item_id': 17764259,
       'user_id': 18},
      {'account_number': '*819',
       'bank_name': 'Central Alabama - Bank',
       'bankid': 88,
       'created_date_y': Timestamp('2015-05-20 08:08:33'),
       'item_account_id': 20637127.0,
       'item_id': 17761624,
       'user_id': 18},
      {'account_number': '*056',
       'bank_name': 'Central Alabama - Bank',
       'bankid': 88,
       'created_date_y': Timestamp('2015-05-20 08:08:33'),
       'item_account_id': 20087284.0,
       'item_id': 17761624,
       'user_id': 18}]}}
```

After converting it into a dictionary, I want to convert this into a JSON. The problem in converting it into json is that the `timestamp` fields give an error as `timestamp is not json serializale`. The code I have so far which does not work as I want is:

```
 import pandas as pd
 #importing files
 df1 = pd.read_excel("C:\\Users\\Desktop\\yod_user.xlsx")
 df2 = pd.read_excel("C:\\Users\\Desktop\\yod_bank.xlsx")

 df1['created_date'] = df1['created_date'].astype(str)
 df2['created_date'] = df2['created_date'].astype(str)

 df1.dtypes
 #id               int64
 #username        object
 #password        object
 #uid              int64
 #created_date    object
 #status           int64
 #dtype: object
 df2.dtypes
 #user_id              int64
 #bankid                      int64
 #account_number             object
 #item_id              int64
 #item_account_id    float64
 #created_date               object
 #bank_name                  object
 #dtype: object

 df_merge = pd.merge(df1, df2, left_on = 'id', right_on ='user_id', how ='inner')
 df_merge.dtypes
 #id                        object
 #username                  object
 #password                  object
 #uid                       object
 #created_date_x            object
 #status                    object
 #user_id                   object
 #bankid                    object
 #account_number            object
 #item_id                   object
 #item_account_id           object
 #created_date_y            object
 #bank_name                 object
 #dtype: object
j = df_merge.groupby(['id', 'username', 'password',   'uid',created_date_x',  'status'], as_index=False)\
         .apply(lambda x: x[['account_number','user_id','bankid', 'item_id', 'item_account_id','created_date_y', 'bank_name' ]].to_dict('r'))\
         .reset_index()\
         .rename(columns={0:'accounts'})\

 j.dtypes
 #id                 int64
 #username          object
 #password          object
 #uid                int64
 #created_date_x    object
 #status             int64
 #accounts          object
 #dtype: object
 jdict = j.to_dict('records')

 import json
 json.dumps(jdict) #This gives an error: TypeError: Object of type     'Timestamp' is not JSON serializable
```

If the initial list can be converted into a json like a dictionary that will also do. Please Help.

Comment: `Timestamp` is a third party module? Have you defined it yourself?

Comment: The `df1` and `df2` are tables from MySQL stored in excel and imported to python. The `astype` does not work

Comment: You need to actually assign the type change: `df1['created_date'] = df1['created_date'].astype(str)`.  Then you'll have date strings when you convert `to_dict()`.

Comment: Do you need to convert `created_date_x`?

Comment: I have two columns with the same name `created_date`. When I merge them, then `_x` and `_y` is added to them. They are already an object.'

Answer (score 0):

Using `astype()` will work.  In your code, you're not actually changing the `dtype` of your date columns.

You have:

```
 df1['created_date'].astype(str)
```

You need:

```
 df1['created_date'] = df1['created_date'].astype(str)
```

Example:

```
dates = pd.date_range("2000","2002",freq="A")
data = {"created_date":dates, "value":range(len(dates))}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

df
  created_date  value
0   2000-12-31      0
1   2001-12-31      1

(df["created_date"].dtype
# datetime64[ns]

df["created_date"] = df["created_date"].astype(str)

df["created_date"].dtype
# object

json.dumps(df.to_dict('records'))
# '[{"created_date": "2000-12-31", "value": 0}, 
    {"created_date": "2001-12-31", "value": 1}]'
```

Comment: I did it, but it still gives the same error when I try to dump it as json. How do I check the datatype of it before converting to json

Comment: Check with `.dtype`.  I added an example.

Comment: `df1['created_date'] = df1['created_date'].astype(str)
df1['created_date'].dtype
dtype('O')`. It gives me this but it does not convert to json.

Comment: It's not clear what you mean here.  Are you saying you're getting the same error about `Timestamp` that you were originally?  If so, you're missing the conversion of some other date or time field in your data.  Use `df.dtypes` to figure out what's a date, and make sure they're all converted.  (Or just do `df.astype(str)`.)

Comment: Yes, the same error of timestamp not being json serializable. I have all dtypes as int64, object or float. I should convert all into str?

Comment: If you're going to end up with a JSON string eventually, then yes, go ahead and convert all to strings.  But that's not really addressing the fact that you're missing something in your code still.  It doesn't make sense that you'd be getting an error about `Timestamp` if `j.dtypes` has no `Timestamp`.  You have additional bugs in your code.  I'd recommend updating your original post with your corrected code and printouts of `dtypes` after each new `df` you make.  (Fix formatting as well, please.)  Then it may be clearer where you're still having a problem.

Comment: I updated the question. Pardon me with the formatting as I don't know how to do it here. I did the best I could.

Comment: I converted all into strings and it worked. But still when I dump into json it gives an error:

`IOPub data rate exceeded.
The notebook server will temporarily stop sending output
to the client in order to avoid crashing it.
To change this limit, set the config variable
`--NotebookApp.iopub_data_rate_limit`.` What am I supposed to with this?

Comment: Glad to hear you have it working. Must be a big file. Your command is trying to show it all in your display frame. That's a separate issue, solved a few different ways here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/43288550/2799941

Comment: I had got this error before also. I couldn't solve it. I tried looking for it at several places but all in vain. I'll look into the link you shared. Thanks anyways :D.

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution to this problem would be to avoid using `Timestamp` entirely. Instead of calling `Timestamp` you could instead use the built in `datetime` module and create a function that returns the actual, numeric timestamp. For example

```
from datetime import datetime
from pytz import utc 

def timestamp_from_str(date_str):

    date = datetime.strptime(date_str, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S') 
    return date.replace(tzinfo=utc).timestamp()
```

Note that the `.timestamp` method is not available in Python 2.7, in which case you will have to calculate the timestamp manually. This is a simple process, but I won't mention it here as it has already been described in depth by [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8778548/6466457).

Comment: `AttributeError: module 'datetime' has no attribute 'strptime'`. I am using python 3

Comment: Did you use `import datetime` or `from datetime import datetime`? The first will throw an error, but the second will work.

Comment: Yep, I did it. defined the function and passed `df1['created_date']`. Still, got the error.

Comment: sorry - there was a typo with the tzinfo. For both myself and the college to my immediate left, copy and pasting the above definition works for the function call `timestamp_from_str('2015-05-20 08:08:33')`.

Comment: It does not work bro. Same error. I am going edit the question with outputs of dtypes and others.

Comment: The attribute error you're quoting is well documented and is specifically caused by the wrong import statement, as discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19480028/attributeerror-module-object-has-no-attribute-strptime)

Comment: I did it by converting everything to string. I have had the following error before also. Any idea how to fix this:

`IOPub data rate exceeded.
The notebook server will temporarily stop sending output
to the client in order to avoid crashing it.
To change this limit, set the config variable
--NotebookApp.iopub_data_rate_limit`.