# How to convert timestamp into string in Python

Tags: python, pandas, strptime

I have a problem with the following code. I get an error "strptime() argument 1 must be str, not Timestamp"

I guess that what I should do is to convert date from timestamp to string but I do not know what to do.

```
class TweetAnalyzer:

    def tweets_to_data_frame(self,ElonMuskTweets):

        df = pd.DataFrame(data=[tweet.text for tweet in ElonMuskTweets],columns=['Tweets'])

        df['Text length'] = np.array ([len(tweet.text)for tweet in ElonMuskTweets])
        df['Date and time of creation'] = np.array ([tweet.created_at for tweet in ElonMuskTweets])
        df['Likes'] = np.array ([tweet.favorite_count for tweet in ElonMuskTweets])
        df['Retweets'] = np.array ([tweet.retweet_count for tweet in ElonMuskTweets])

        list_of_dates = []   
        list_of_times = []

        for date in df['Date and time of creation']:

            date_time_obj = datetime.strptime(date, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S') 
            list_of_dates.append(date_time_obj.date())  
            list_of_times.append(date_time_obj.time())

            df['Date'] = list_of_dates
            df['Time'] = list_of_times

            df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])

            start_date = '2018-04-13'
            end_date = '2019-04-13'

            mask1 = (df['Date'] >= start_date) & (df['Date'] <= end_date)
            MuskTweets18_19 = df.loc[mask1]  

            return MuskTweets18_19.to_csv ('elonmusk_tweets.csv',index=False)
```

I get the error in

```
date_time_obj = datetime.strptime(date, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
```

How can I solve this prolem?
Thank you in advance

Comment: Looks like Python. Please use [Edit] and add a language-specific tag.

Comment: Yes, it is Python. Thank you for the advice!

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Can you coerce the data type to a string to perform this calculation?

```py
date_time_obj = datetime.strptime(str(date), '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
```

Comment: I did not think it could work but it does! Thank you a lot

Answer (score 9):

If it says "strptime() argument 1 must be str, not Timestamp", likely that you already have the [`pandas.Timestamp`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Timestamp.html) object, i.e., it is not a string but a parsed date time, only it is in Pandas' format, not Python's. So to convert, use this:

```
date_time_obj = date.to_pydatetime()
```

instead of `date_time_obj = datetime.strptime(date, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')`

Answer (score 8):

If the object is a Python Timestamp, you can implement:

```
timestamp = Timestamp('2017-11-12 00:00:00')

str_timestamp = str(timestamp)
```

Comment: This is a duplicate of [this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55941915/16775594). Please don't post duplicate answers. See [answer] for more information.

Comment: Downvoted because: 1/ there is no such thing as a "Python Timestamp". There is a pandas.Timestamp, though. 2/ This answer is incomplete: a) it doesn't take its input from OP's code (it should be `date`, not `'2017-11-12 00:00:00'`). b) the resulting str_timestamp cannot be used as-is in OP's code, it needs to be converted to a datetime, as shown in the anwser linked in the comment above mine. It could be improved by showing that `date` (which is a pandas.Timestamp) can be used directly instead of converting it to string then datetime: pandas.Timestamp also has a `time()` and `date()` methods.

Answer (score 1):

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime

base = pd.to_datetime("2022-10-10")
date_list = [datetime.datetime.strftime(pd.to_datetime(base - datetime.timedelta(days=x)),"%Y-%m-%d") for x in range(7)]
print(date_list)
```

output will be

```
['2022-10-10',
 '2022-10-09',
 '2022-10-08',
 '2022-10-07',
 '2022-10-06',
 '2022-10-05',
 '2022-10-04']
```

Answer (score 0):

Just adding to the above answers as ran into the following probem using the solutions provided:

```
AttributeError: module 'datetime' has no attribute 'strptime'
```

Based on the answer found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19480028/attributeerror-datetime-module-has-no-attribute-strptime), you need to either coerce the timestamp into a string like this:

```
date_time_obj = datetime.datetime.strptime(str(date), '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
```

Or make sure to import the class and not just the module like this:

```
from datetime import datetime
```