# How to play around with JSON date format?

Tags: python, json, data-science

I have a JSON date data set and trying to calculate the time difference between two different JSON DateTime.

For example :

```
'2015-01-28T21:41:38.508275' - '2015-01-28T21:41:34.921589'
```

Please look at the python code below:

```py
#let's say 'time' is my data frame and JSON formatted time values are under the 'due_date' column
time_spent = time.iloc[2]['due_date'] - time.iloc[10]['due_date']
```

This doesn't work. I also tried to cast each operand to int, but it also didn't help. What are the different ways to perform this calculation?

Comment: They are actually just strings. Try convert them to `datetime`,

Comment: Like @JoYSword said, there is no such thing as a json date format: https://www.json.org

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use parser from dateutil.

Something like that:

```
from dateutil.parser import parse

first_date_obj = parse("2015-01-28T21:41:38.508275")
second_date_obj = parse("2015-02-28T21:41:38.508275")
print(second_date_obj - first_date_obj)
```

You can also access the year, month, day of the date object like that:

```
print(first_date_obj.year)
print(first_date_obj.month)
print(first_date_obj.day)
# and so on
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
from datetime import datetime

date_format = '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f'

d2 = time.iloc[2]['due_date']
d1 = time.iloc[10]['due_date']

time_spent = datetime.strptime(d2, date_format) - datetime.strptime(d1, date_format)

print(time_spent.days) # 0
print(time_spent.microseconds) # 586686
print(time_spent.seconds) # 3
print(time_spent.total_seconds()) # 3.586686
```

Comment: when I try to use your code, it gives me the following error: module 'datetime' has noo attribute 'strptime'

Comment: @MertZamir I think you `import datetime`, if you are import like that you can use `datetime.datetime.strptime()`. I think you face this [error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19480028/attributeerror-datetime-module-has-no-attribute-strptime) and check the verified [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19480045/6194097).

Answer (score 0):

The easiest thing to do is to use the pandas datetime capability (since you are already using iloc I assume you are using pandas). You can convert the entire dataframe column labeled due_date to be a pandas datetime datatype using

```
import pandas as pd
time['due_date'] = pd.to_datetime(time['due_date']
```

then calculate the time difference you want using

```
time_spent = time.iloc[2]['due_date'] - time.iloc[10]['due_date']
```

`time_spent` will be a pandas timedelta object that you can then manipulate as necessary.

See https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/timeseries.html and https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/timedeltas.html.