# Create a function that is able to extract specific elements from a directory name?

Tags: python, list, function, directory

I need to create a function that is able to extract certain information from a directory name. I am using a list of dict for this situation. I have two fields (keys) that have different values stored in them, dname (shows the path to the file) and fname (shows the name of the file). The example information below is already stored in a list of dict, called fInfos.

```
dname="opgh_mini/12345-12345 - James Brown - 28 may 2021 1135 AM", 
fname="textfile.txt"
```

*I say list of dict because this is what the format actually looks like: `{ 'dname': 'opgh_mini/12345-12345 - James Brown - 28 may 2021 1135 AM', 'fname': 'textfile.txt }`, it just looks different when I run it in the terminal.*

My function needs to be able to extract the name and date of a directory name and then put it into two new fields (keys). It should look like this.

```
dname="opgh_mini/12345-12345 - James Brown - 28 may 2021 1135 AM", 
fname="textfile.txt", suser="James Brown", sdate="2021-05-28"
```

I then need to append these results to a new list called fInfosUpdated. I first wanted to use slice, but then I realized that not all directory names have the same length, so this is not going to work. Does anyone know how I can make this work? This is my code so far.

Edit:

```
def extractInfo(fInfos):
    fInfosUpdated = []
    data = "opgh_mini/12345-12345 - James Brown - 28 may 2021 1135 AM"
    splitted_data = data.split("-")
    date = splitted_data[-1]
    name = splitted_data[-2]
    for dir in fInfos:
        date = datetime.strptime(dir['dname'].split("-")[-1].strip()).strftime('%Y-%m-%D')
        fInfosUpdated.append( {'dname': dir['dname'], 'suser': dir['dname'].split("-")[-2].strip(), 'fname': dir['fname'], 'sdate': date} )
    return fInfosUpdated
```

Comment: Do I understand correctly that the fact that `fname` exists is totally irrelevant?

Comment: @mkrieger1, how do you mean irrelevant?

Comment: I mean it does not matter. You want to extract information from `dname`, and `fname` has nothing to do with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If all of your files are written in the same way (file path - Name - Date), you can split the dname with "-" and get the infos.

```
data = "opgh_mini/12345-12345 - James Brown - 28 may 2021 1135 AM"

splitted_data = data.split("-")
date = splitted_data[-1]
name = splitted_data[-2]

print(date) # ' 28 may 2021 1135 AM' 
print(name) # ' James Brown '
```

As for your function, it should look like this :

```
import datetime

def extractInfo(fInfos):
    fInfosUpdated = []
    for dir in fInfos :
        date = datetime.strptime(dir['dname'].split("-")[-1].strip()).strftime("%Y-%m-%D")
        fInfosUpdated.append({'dname' = dir['dname'], 'suser' = dir['dname'].split("-")[-2].strip(), 'fname' = dir['fname'],'sdate'=date})
    return fInfosUpdated
```

I don't know how you get the fname value though

Comment: Sorry, I think I need to clarify the fname part a bit. I need to show different kinds of information, so the directory name/path (dname), the filename (fname), the user and the date. The dname and fname parts were already stored in my list. Maybe it was not necessary to mention that, but I didn't really think that it would make you guys confused. Just wanted to show y'all what my list already contains. Thanks for the help.

Comment: No problem, I edited myanswer to fit your problem. Does it answer your question ?

Comment: Yes, thank you very much. I had to change the fInfosUpdated.append sentence a bit but it works. I'm now struggling with the date part, I have to change that to this format '2021-05-28'.

Comment: Indeed, I forgot a closing } when first writing the function. I edited it, plus added the date format (that you can find in @tituszban's answer). Feel free to accept and upvote if our answers answer your initial question.

Comment: Sorry for the late answer, I was trying to solve a small problem that I'm dealing with right now with the datetime, it says that module datetime has no attribute called 'strptime', already tried to change the way I import it, but that doesn't work. I think it's because of that 1135 AM.

Comment: Try to import datetime with `from datetime import datetime `instead of just `import datetime` . It should work

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I already tried that, but when I do that it gives this error back: date = datetime.strptime(dir['dname'].split("-")[-1].strip()).strftime('%Y-%m-%D')
TypeError: strptime() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given). 

I changed the code in the post

Comment: Check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19480028/attributeerror-datetime-module-has-no-attribute-strptime . You have to change the line to `date = datetime.datetime.strptime(dir['dname'].split("-")[-1].strip(),"%Y-%m-%D")`

Comment: This is weird. Tried everything, nothing works. I keep getting this error. date = datetime.datetime.strptime(dir['dname'].split("-")[-1].strip(),"%Y-%m-%D")
AttributeError: type object 'datetime.datetime' has no attribute 'datetime'. I already changed the import, changed it back to import datetime, but it doesn't work. I'm not really sure whats causing this problem.

Comment: That is indeed weird and it's hard to help without being able to reproduce. A workaround would be to use slice instead of datetime.strftime() like : `date= dir['dname'].split("-")[-1].strip()[:-7] `. But you have to be sure that date always contains hours/minutes + AM or PM. Definitely not the cleanest way to do it but it work.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I was already trying that, because I cannot seem to make it work otherwise. It is now '13 June 2021', got rid of the AM and PM. I now have to find a way to convert this to the right format '2021-06-13'.

Comment: There is a lot of answered questions and documentation about reformatting dates. I'll let you find them. Datetime and strftime is definitely the cleanest and easiest. You should try to fix the import error, it seems to be well documented on Stack Overflow aswell

Answer (score 0):

## Extracting the relevant data

You can split on the `-`, and get each part you need:

```py
fields = dname.split("-")
date = fields[-1].strip()  # "28 may 2021 1135 AM"
name = fields[-2].strip()  # "James Brown"
```

`.strip()` is needed to remove the leading and traling spaces

## Changing the date format

You need to parse the date and transform it to a different format:

```py
import datetime

datetime.strptime(date).strftime("%Y-%m-%D")  # 2021-05-28
```