# Reformat a list of dates from "/" to "-" (using python)

Tags: python, list, date, format, reformatting

I have a list of dates.

```
['1/12/2022', '1/13/2022','1/17/2022']
```

How do I reformat them to look like this:

```
['2022-1-12', '2022-1-13','2022-1-17']
```

**EDIT:** My original post asked about the wrong format. I've corrected it because I meant for the the format to be "Year-Month-Day"

Comment: What programming language are you using? (Python, Java, C, C++, C# JS)

Comment: I am using python

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming you are using Python... Please correct me if I am wrong.  You can loop through the list of dates using a enumerated for-loop (enumerate(list) function lets you know the index of each value during the loop) with each date, use the .replace() method of str to replace '/' with '-' like this:

```
list_of_dates = ['1/12/2022', '1/13/2022','1/17/2022']
for i, date in enumerate(list_of_dates):
    list_of_dates[i] = date.replace('/', '-')
```

or use list comprehension like this (thank you @Eli Harold ):

```
list_of_dates = [date.replace('/', '-') for date in list_of_dates]
```

If you want to change the order of the numbers in the date string you can split them by the '/' or '-' into a new list and change the order if you want like this:

```
for i, date in enumerate(list_of_dates):
    month, day, year = date.split('-') # assuming you already changed it to dashes
    list_of_dates[i] = f'{day}-{month}-{year}'
```

Comment: The second option is called list comprehension not "shorthand for-loops" just an FYI.

Comment: IS there a way to make the format Year-Month-Day?

Comment: sure let me add that

Comment: Thanks for all of your help.

Answer (score 1):

you can use strptime

```
from datetime import datetime

dates = []
for date_str in ['1/12/2022', '1/13/2022','1/17/2022']:
   date = datetime.strptime(date_str, '%m/%d/%Y')
   dates.append(date.strftime('%m-%d-%Y'))
```

Comment: my error: strptime is not an attribute of datetime

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19480028/attributeerror-datetime-module-has-no-attribute-strptime if you have issue with datetime  you can look here

Answer (score 1):

```
from datetime import datetime

dates = [datetime.strptime(x, "%-m/%-d/%Y") for x in list_of_dates]
new_dates = [x.strftime("%Y-%-m-%-d") for x in dates]
```

Comment: I keep getting this error: module 'datetime' has no attribute 'strptime'

Comment: nevermind. I had to type datetime.datetime.strptime for it to work.

Comment: That's because you wrote ``import datetime`` and not ``from datetime import datetime`` like I asked you to.

Answer (score 1):

I opted to split the individual dates and then add in the "-" delimiter after the fact, but you could also replace those on iteration. Once your data has been transformed, I just pushed it into a new list of reformatted dates.

This may not result in the best performance for longer iterations, though.

```py
dates = ['1/12/2022', '1/13/2022','1/17/2022']
newdates = []
    for x in range(0, len(dates)):
        split_date = dates[x].split('/')
        month = split_date[0]
        day = split_date[1]
        year = split_date[2]
        your_date = year +"-"+month+"-"+day
        newdates.apppend(your_date)
        print(your_date)
```

And the output:

```
2022-1-12
2022-1-13
2022-1-17
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
dates = ['1/12/2022', '1/13/2022','1/17/2022']
dates = [x.replace('/', '-') for x in dates]
```

Comment: This is a copy of Jacob's answer.

Comment: I add it at the same time. Sorry.

Comment: Don't worry about it. It happens to everyone. I personally like that your answer showcases the comprehension. I suggest you elaborate on it some more so that it is not a "code only answer" by explaining what it does or why it might be easer to understand or more efficient than a `for` loop.