# "module.__init__() takes at most 2 arguments (3 given)" when creating instance of a subclass

Tags: python, class, inheritance, initialization

I have a class named `Board` that acts as a superclass. 
It is basically a randomly generated Sudoku Board with 81 numbers placing correctly on it by the rules.

Then I defined a subclass named `normalSudoku` where it will be initialized with a parameter "difficulties"(a string) where it will decide how many empty entries will appear on the Sudoku.

When I created an instance of normalSudoku and try to print it out to see if it works, the following error pops out:

```
TypeError: module.__init__() takes at most 2 arguments (3 given)
```

I am not sure what I did wrong and I am a bit confused about the use of `self` and object initialization in python.

My `Board` Class:

```
class Board(object):    
    def __init__(self):
        self.sudoku = self.__create__()

    def __create__(self):
       #generateion of board goes here
       #it will return a 9x9 2d-list
```

My `normalSudoku` Class:

```
import Board
import random

class normalSudoku(Board):
    def __init__(self,difficulties):
        Board.Board.__init__(self)
        self.Create_Empty_Entries(self,difficulties)

    def Create_Empty_Entries(self, difficulties):
        numbers = list(range(0,9))
        if difficulties == "Easy":
            for x in range(25):
                a = random.choice(numbers)
                b = random.choice(numbers)
                self.sudoku[a][b] = None
        elif difficulties == "Medium":
            for x in range(35):
                a = random.choice(numbers)
                b = random.choice(numbers)
                self.sudoku[a][b] = None
        elif difficulties == "Hard":
            for x in range(45):
                a = random.choice(numbers)
                b = random.choice(numbers)
                self.sudoku[a][b] = None
        elif difficulties == "Expert":
            for x in range(65):
                a = random.choice(numbers)
                b = random.choice(numbers)
                self.sudoku[a][b] = None
        else:
            print("The Level of Difficulty you chose does not exist.")
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [TypeError: module.\_\_init\_\_() takes at most 2 arguments (3 given)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14583761/typeerror-module-init-takes-at-most-2-arguments-3-given)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are trying to create a subclass of a **module**, not your base class.

You import the module here:

```
import Board
```

then try to subclass that directly:

```
class normalSudoku(Board):
```

`Board` is the module. If the class is named the same, it's an attribute on the module:

```
class normalSudoku(Board.Board):
    def __init__(self,difficulties):
        Board.Board.__init__(self)
```

You already had the `__init__` call call correct, just not the base class reference.

Alternatively, import the class from the module:

```
from Board import Board
```

and leave your `class` definition the same but adjust the `__init__` call:

```
class normalSudoku(Board):
    def __init__(self,difficulties):
        Board.__init__(self)
```

Some other pointers:

- Don't use `__name__` dunder (double underscore) names. Those are [reserved by Python for future system use](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#reserved-classes-of-identifiers), and thus can lead to forward compatibility issues.
- Try to follow the [Python PEP 8 naming conventions](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#naming-conventions); it'll lead to more clarity. Modules are generally named using `lower_case_with_underscores` names, classes use `CamelCase`. Your module should be named `board`, the class `Board`, making the difference obvious. The same goes for methods; those should be lowercase too.

Comment: Thank you very much for pointing out my mistakes! Your answer is really helpful. I have fixed all the errors now and had a better understanding of classes structure in python. :)

Answer (score 1):

In addtition to [Martjin Pieters' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46130992/4832333), your line 
`self.Create_Empty_Entries(self,difficulties)` is also incorrect, it should be `self.Create_Empty_Entries(difficulties)`.

Consider this :

```
>>> class Foo(object):
    def foo(self):
        return self


>>> print Foo
<class '__main__.Foo'>
>>> instance = Foo()
>>> print instance
<__main__.Foo object at 0x02FFF7F0>
>>> print instance.foo() #as you can see, I don't pass any argument here
<__main__.Foo object at 0x02FFF7F0> #however you can note that internally, "instance" passed itself as "foo()" first argument
```

Comment: yeah that too, I could say that when a class calls its member function, it automatically passes itself as its first argument right?

Comment: Yup, but not quite : you've got it, but just be sure to make the difference between the class, and its instance. There are subtleties.

Your satement is correct if the method called is a "classmethod" (defined with the decorator `@classmethod`. For what you mean, you should say :
When an instance calls its member method, it automatically passes itself as its first argument