# Python Inheritance initialize problems

Tags: python, inheritance

I have threading class in serverThread.py file as shown:

```
import threading

class serverThread(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, name):
        try:
            threading.Thread.__init__(self)
            self.name = name
        except:
            exit()

    def run(self):
           print("Hello")
```

I created a new project.I want to inherit class from above class as shown:

```
import serverThread


class tcpThread(serverThread):
    def __init__(self, name):
        serverThread.__init__(self,name)

    def run():
        serverThread.run(self)


t1 = tcpThread("Tcp Server")
t1.start()
```

When I run this script gives me error:

> Error:
>       Traceback (most recent call last):                                                                                        File "serverTcpThread.py", line 4, in <module>                                                                            class tcpThread(serverThread):                                                                                      TypeError: module.__init__() takes at most 2 arguments (3 given)

[image]

Comment: I've answered but it seems that the error you're reporting doesn't happen here. The other error _is_ real, though.

Comment: also: paste the error + traceback _as text_. Images aren't done for that.

Comment: `from serverThread import serverThread`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [TypeError: module.\_\_init\_\_() takes at most 2 arguments (3 given)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14583761/typeerror-module-init-takes-at-most-2-arguments-3-given)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error you're reporting is probably because the base class is imported from a bad path, cannot reproduce here.

That said, there's another (similar) error: when redefining the `run` method, you have to pass the `self` parameter

```
class tcpThread(serverThread):
    def __init__(self, name):
        serverThread.__init__(self,name)

    def run(self):
        serverThread.run(self)
```

the code runs fine after that. note that there's no need to redefine the `run` method only to call the parent method.

Comment: are you sure you're not importing another version of your mother class? in another file?

Comment: Have you tried it on your own computer.Because it is very simple code.If you could run, I should look at my side very carefully

Comment: of course I tried. I pasted both objects in the same file and it worked (apart from this self issue)