# TypeError: module() takes at most 2 arguments (3 given)

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

idk what i did wrong for this error code to come but pls help  `File "/Users/jenniferkarlsson/Desktop/TimmyReWrite/cogs/levelsys.py", line 17, in <module> class levelsys(commands.cog): TypeError: module() takes at most 2 arguments (3 given)` but it would be great if you could help me because this error code is gonna be the end of me it's so annoying Idk what to do because I'm pretty new to discord.py and I cant stand this error code I've been stuck on it for 3hours now here is my code if you need it would be great if you could help me Thanks

```py
import discord
import dns
from discord import file
from discord.ext import commands
from pymongo import MongoClient

level = ["Bronze", "Silver", "Gold"]
levelnum = [5, 10, 15]

cluster = MongoClient(
    "mongodb+srv://myusername:<mypassword>@cluster0.47irg.mongodb.net/myFirstDatabase?retryWrites=true&w=majority")

leveling = "discord", "leveling"


class levelsys(commands.cog):
    def __init__(self, bot):
        self.bot = bot

        @commands.Cog.listener()
        async def on_ready(ctx):
            print("lvl system is up and running")

        @commands.Cog.listener()
        async def on_message(self, message, ctx=None):
            stats = leveling.find_one({"id": message.author.id})
            if not message.author.bot:
                if stats is None:
                    newuser = {"id": message.author.id, "xp": 1}
                    leveling.insert_one(newuser)
                else:
                    xp = stats["xp"] + 5
                    leveling.update_one({"id": message.author.id}, {"$set": {xp}})
                    lvl = 0
                    while True:
                        if xp < ((50 * (lvl ** 2)) + (50 * (lvl - 1))):
                            break
                        lvl += 1
                        xp -= ((50 * (lvl - 1) ** 2) + (50 * (lvl - 1)))
                        if xp == 0:
                            with open('giphy.gif', 'rb') as f:
                                pictures = discord.File(f)
                                ss = f"Nice {message.author.mention} you leveled up to level {lvl} <:lvlup:858026926832484352>"
                            await message.channel.send(ss)
                            for i in range(len(level)):
                                if lvl == levelnum[i]:
                                    await message.author.add_roles(
                                        discord.utils.get(message.author.guild.roles, name=level[i]))
                                    embed = discord.Embed(
                                        description=f"{message.author.mention} you have gotten the {level[i]} rank",
                                        color=discord.Colour.light_grey())
                                    embed.set_thumbnail(url=message.author.avatar_url)
                                    await ctx.send(embed=embed)

        @commands.command()
        async def rank(ctx, self):
            stats = leveling.find_one({"id": ctx.author.id})
            if stats is None:
                embed = discord.Embed(description="You haven't sent any messages, no rank",
                                      color=discord.Colour.light_grey())
                await ctx.send(embed=embed)
            else:
                xp = stats["xp"]
                lvl = 0
                rankers = 0
                while True:
                    if xp < ((50 * (lvl ** 2)) + (50 * (lvl - 1))):
                        break
                    lvl += 1
                xp -= ((50 * (lvl - 1) ** 2) + (50 * (lvl - 1)))
                boxes = int((xp / (200 ** ((1 / 2) * lvl))) * 20)
                rank = leveling.find().sort("xp", - 1)
                for x in rank:
                    rank += 1
                    if stats["id"] == x["id"]:
                        break
                embed = discord.Embed(title="{}'s level stats".format(ctx.author.name))
                embed.add_field(name="Name", value=ctx.author.mention, inline=True)
                embed.add_field(name="XP", value=f"{xp}/{int(200 * ((1 / 2) * lvl))}", inline=True)
                embed.add_field(name="Rank", value=f"{rank}/{ctx.guild.member_count}", inline=True)
                embed.add_field(name="Progress bar [lvl]",
                                value=boxes * ":blue_square:" + (20 - boxes) * "white_square", inline=False)
                embed.set_thumbnail(url=ctx.author.avatar_url)
                await ctx.send(embed=embed)

        @commands.command()
        async def lvlleaderboard(self, ctx, rankings=None):
            rankings == leveling.find().sort("xp", - 1)
            i = 1
            embed = discord.Embed(title="Rankings", color=discord.Colour.light_grey())
            for x in rankings:
                try:
                    temp = ctx.guild.get_member(x["id"])
                    tempxp = x["xp"]
                    embed.add_field(name=f"{i}: {temp.name}", value=f"Total XP:{tempxp}", inline=False)
                    i += 1
                except:
                    pass
                if i == 11:
                    break
                await ctx.send(embed=embed)


def setup(client):
    client.add_cog(levelsys(bot))
```

Comment: Your identation is really messed up, please fix it.

Comment: how do i fix it

Comment: Looks like it's the same as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14583761/typeerror-module-init-takes-at-most-2-arguments-3-given) problem

Answer (score 2):

ignore my other comment

> class levelsys(commands.cog):

should be

> class levelsys(commands.Cog):

Subtle difference, but the second has a capital "C" in Cog