# The difference between sys.argv & argv?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

I don't understand the difference between `sys.argv` and just `argv`, Nothing online gives me the concept that I understand. if both are the same! When do we use `sys.argv` and when to use `argv` ?

if not what is the `sys.argv`. I've idea what is the `argv`.

Comment: It sounds like one time you `import sys` and the other time you did not.

Comment: http://effbot.org/zone/import-confusion.htm

Comment: @Joel Cornett, This source has been very informative for me, Thank you very much.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

They're the same thing, it just depends on how you write the import statement.

```
import sys
```

If you write this, then you must reference `sys.argv`.

```
from sys import argv
from sys import *
```

If you write either of those, then you can write simply `argv` without the `sys.` qualifier.

Comment: Clear and simple, Thank you very much.

Comment: In the 2nd type of importing module, we can only write "argv". "sys.argv" will give error "name 'sys' is not defined.

Comment: Worth noting that the `from ... import *` form is very seldom a good thing to do: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2360724/in-python-what-exactly-does-import-import)

Answer (score 1):

its the same thing, ex; of different arguments to see what happens.

```
from __future__ import print_function
import sys
print(sys.argv, len(sys.argv))

> python print_args.py
['print_args.py'] 1

> python print_args.py foo and bar
['print_args.py', 'foo', 'and', 'bar'] 4

> python print_args.py "foo and bar"
['print_args.py', 'foo and bar'] 2

> python print_args.py "foo and bar" and baz
['print_args.py', 'foo and bar', 'and', 'baz'] 4
```

As you can see, the command-line arguments include the script name but not the interpreter name. In this sense, Python treats the script as the executable. If you need to know the name of the executable (python in this case), you can use sys.executable.

Comment: @Charles, Actually there is no difference