# import file but reports error NameError: name 'something' is not defined

Tags: python, import

testa.py

```
class A:

    s1 = 333
    __age = 0

    def __init__(self,age ):
        self.__age=age
        return

    def __del__(self):  

        return  
    #private
    def __doSomething(self, s): 
        print self.__age 
        return            
    #public
    def doSomething(self, s):  
        self.__doSomething(s)    
        print s
```

test.py

```
import sys
import testa

a=A(111)
a.doSomething('222')
```

run

```
python test.py
```

it reports error:

```
NameError: name 'A' is not defined
```

your comment welcome

Comment: use 'testa.A' or import it like that: 'from testa import A'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use
`a=testa.A(111)`

You must name the package unless you import `A` explicitly e.g

`from testa import A`

Comment: Discounting that you'd ever dream of using `from testa import *`

Comment: @Paul Rooney  'from testa import *' is better or not?

Comment: No it's generally considered [bad practice](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2360724/in-python-what-exactly-does-import-import).

Answer (score 0):

Remember this:

Doing: `import mymodule` does not import the whole methods and attributes of `mymodule` to the namespace, so you will need to refer to `mymodule`, everytime you need a method or attribute from it, using the `.` notation, example:

```
x = mymodule.mymethod()
```

However, if you use:

```
from mymodule import *
```

This will bring every method and attribute of `mymodule` into the namespace and they are available directly, so you don't need to refer to `mymodule` each time you need to call one of its method or attribute, example:

```
from mymodule import *

x = mymethod()  #mymethod being a method from mymodule
```

You can also import specific method if you don't want to bring the whole module:

```
from mymodule import myMethod
```

For further details, read the Python docs:

https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html