# "from math import sqrt" works but "import math" does not work. What is the reason?

Tags: python, module, komodo

I am pretty new in programming, just learning python.

I'm using Komodo Edit 9.0 to write codes. So, when I write "from math import sqrt", I can use the "sqrt" function without any problem. But if I only write "import math", then "sqrt" function of that module doesn't work. What is the reason behind this? Can I fix it somehow?

Comment: you are not using `math.sqrt()` to access the above mentioned method.

Comment: You need to use math.sqr

Comment: I can accept answer after 15 minutes may be. Ok, I will do that. Thanks. @randomusername

Comment: FWIW, if you just want to do square roots, don't bother importing `sqrt`. Instead of `sqrt(x)` just do `x ** 0.5` - the built-in exponentiation operator is efficient & saves a function call.

Comment: No, I was just trying to understand how module works. Anyway, thanks for your kind suggestion. @PM2Ring

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You have two options:

```
import math
math.sqrt()
```

will import the `math` module into its own namespace. This means that function names have to be prefixed with `math`. This is good practice because it avoids conflicts and won't overwrite a function that was already imported into the current namespace.

Alternatively:

```
from math import *
sqrt()
```

will import everything from the `math` module into the current namespace. [That can be problematic](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2360808/2202669).

Comment: However, it's generally not a good idea to do star imports in a normal script. See [Why is “import *” bad?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2386714/4014959)

Comment: In place of using *, I can use "from module_name import func1, func2, func3, ... ," etc. That would be better I guess.

Comment: @SheikhAhmadShah Yes, but you could still overwrite an existing function by accident.

Comment: you can also do 
    `from math import sqrt`
and 
    `from math import sqrt as square_root_function`

So I guess that makes **4** Options

Answer (score 4):

If you only `import math` to call `sqrt` function you need to do this:

```
In [1]: import math

In [2]: x = 2

In [3]: math.sqrt(x)
Out[3]: 1.4142135623730951
```

This is because `from math import sqrt` brings you the `sqrt` function, but `import math` only brings you the module.

Comment: @Maverick maybe you are thinking of 2^2?

Comment: @meepi I am actually confused, as I never noticed this result. Ideally square root should be 2**2 = 4 and that is what you expect in math.sqrt(2) would return. could you please explain?

Comment: @Maverick you are thinking of squared, not square root.  squared is an exponent like  `2**2 = 4` and `2**3 = 8`.  square root is `a number that produces a specified quantity when multiplied by itself.`  `1.4142135623730951 * 1.4142135623730951 ≈ 2`

Comment: and what does 2^2 or 4^4 should result in? And I came to this post finding distance between two coordinates (lat, long) and in all those formulas they are writing sqrt, so not sure what to use for the right result.

Comment: @Maverick 2^2 is just and 4^4 is just notation for an exponent.  They are identical to `2**2` is just and `4**4`.  Calculating the distance between 2 coordinates on our earth uses the Haversine formula, which does indeed use square roots

Comment: @Maverick yes look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4913349/haversine-formula-in-python-bearing-and-distance-between-two-gps-points

Comment: thanks for the info you gave, I really appreciate it!

Answer (score 3):

When you only use `import math` the `sqrt` function comes in under a different name: `math.sqrt`.

Answer (score 2):

If you need a square root, you can also just exponentiate a number by 0.5.

```
144 ** 0.5
```

gives the result:

```
12.0
```

Answer (score 0):

If the command `Import math` is present more than once you will get the error: UnboundLocalError: local variable 'math' referenced before assignment