# What is the difference between `import turtle` and `from turtle import *`?

Tags: python, turtle-graphics

Besides the syntactic differences, I do not understand what the difference between `import turtle` and `from turtle import *` is, as both methods appear to produce the same result:

**Method 1**

```
import turtle

t = turtle.Pen()

# rest of program...
```

---

**Method 2**

```
# Method 2:

from turtle import *

t = Turtle()

# rest of program...
```

---

One Internet tutorial I followed used Method 1 and another used Method 2. What is the difference between the two and when should I use each one?

Comment: The difference is, well, obvious -- one of them keeps your namespaces separate, the other doesn't. In general, use the `import turtle` approach -- that way you always know which module something refers to, which can get extremely confusing when there are multiple `from something import *`s.

Comment: method one only loads `turtle` into name space.  Thus you have to say `turtle.Pen()`  Method 2 loads 'everything' from turtle into namespace.  Generally considered bad practice.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy: thanks for your input. It's only obvious if you know the answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### Method 1

You are simply importing the package `turtle` and as you may already know, you are unable to use a variable that has not been declared. Thus, you must reference every item with the package name as a prefix like `turtle.Pen` or `turtle.Turtle`.

#### Method 2

You are not importing the package `turtle` and thus you can not use it at all. In fact, you are actually importing every member from the namespace and thus you can just use the names of the items as is as seen in `Pen` or `Turtle` which are defined to be inclusive of the namespace.

Comment: Not strictly true. 
https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html#importing-from-a-package

"If __all__ is not defined, the statement from sound.effects import * does not import all submodules from the package sound.effects into the current namespace; it only ensures that the package sound.effects has been imported (possibly running any initialization code in __init__.py) and then imports whatever names are defined in the package."

If __all__ is defined, however, the submodules are actually imported directly.

Comment: In this scenario yes, as it has been defined in that way in `__init__.py`

Comment: @AlexanderHuszagh See edits to answer.

Answer (score 2):

Besides purely semantics, there's very good reason to not do:

```
from module import *
```

It pollutes the namespace and you have no easy way of finding what you just included.

By stating:

```
import module
```

You load the module into the namespace but restrict everything within. This lets you know precisely what you imported, and so if you have module.a and a defined, you don't have to worry about over-writing module.a.

It has the same import statement, as the link above.

The rest depends on the package structure: specifically whether the module leaves a blank **init**.py or defines the modules via **all** = [...]

If **all** is defined, it imports as those submodules, if not, it imports the module and then renames the submodules.

As shown here, the import * variety is highly discouraged (some Pythonistas have even stated they wished it was never allowed):
[What exactly does "import *" import?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2360724/in-python-what-exactly-does-import-import)

Answer (score 2):

"import turtle brings" the module and "from turtle import *" brings objects from the module.

If I do

```
import sys
```

I type

```
sys.exit()
```

if I do

```
from sys import *
```

I type just

```
exit()
```