# Transition from MATLAB to Python

Tags: python, matlab

I know this question has been asked before but I can't make heads or tails of what the answer means.

I am making the transition from MATLAB to Python.  In MATLAB I can write my own functions and use them in my code.  I know I can do the same thing in Python.  But I am having a hard time figuring out how to do it.

What I would like to do it create a file with multiple function definitions and then import it into Python like any other module.

First, is this the proper way of thinking it about it?  Or do I just need to create multiple definition files for each function?

Second, if it is the proper way of thinking about it how do I access the file?  I know you have to set the PYTHONPATH.  I have looked at it and where it is looking makes no sense to me.

As an Example:  I created a folder called User.  In it I have a python function called ted.py.  I put said file where the rest of the library files are located (as in numpy or scipy). I want to import the file called User.  How can I do this?

After working with Python for awhile I get it.  As long as the file is in the same directory and you use the import properly you can use one , some or all of the function definitions in the file.

Comment: yes, you are in right track. Every `py` file can be imported as a module. Just write `from filename import functionName` and you are done.

Comment: You can also `import sys; sys.path.append('dirname')` to add `dirname` to your python path for importing.

Comment: Neither of these works.  No matter what I do it keeps telling me that the directory does not exist.

Comment: Ok, I can install individual .py files.  But if I want to install all the files in a folder is what I am having a problem with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have an un-matlab-like (matlab-unlike? dis-matlab-like?) option of putting multiple function definitions into the same `.py` file. Once the file -- say, `fundefs.py` -- is on your path, possibly through having issued `import sys; sys.path.append('path/to/fundefs');`, you can import it

1. through `import fundefs`, after which you can access the functions therein by `fundefs.fun1`, `fundefs.fun2` etc.
2. through `from fundefs import *`, which will throw all the functions into your current namespace. This is generally discouraged (and frowned upon) for larger modules as it will pollute your namespace, but for a few functions of your own this might just be what you're after. See also [this very informative answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2360808/5067311) (and also comments therein).
3. as a middle ground through `import very_long_and_descriptive_module_name as shorthand` to access your functions as `shorthand.fun1`, `shorthand.fun2` etc. (in the obvious case if your definitions are in the file `very_long_and_descriptive_module_name.py`)

Answer (score 0):

You don't import User.  What you want is to `import ted`.  Typically, you would put ted.py in the same folder as your main python file, not in a separate folder.