# name 'STDOUT' is not defined though subprocess is imported

Tags: python, constants

i get error while plainly using STDOUT

```
>>> import subprocess
>>>print STDOUT
```

**Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "", line 1, in 
NameError: name 'STDOUT' is not defined**

it also works with

```
from subprocess import STDOUT
```

But what if there are many such constants in the module, is there a way to import any such constants defined in a module without mentioning them explicitly.

Comment: while using subprocess.STDOUT it works 

    >>>print subprocess.STDOUT
    -2
    >>>>

Answer (score 8):

You need to tell Python where to find "STDOUT", i.e. in the 'subprocess' module. That's why when you specify "subprocess.STDOUT" it works. If you want to be able to refer to STDOUT without always having to name the module, import it like this:

```
from subprocess import STDOUT
```

or, if you are using all of the functions and classes from subprocess, you can import them all like this

```
from subprocess import *
```

but it is recommended you avoid this whenever possible for a lot of good reasons (see [What exactly does "import *" import?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2360724/in-python-what-exactly-does-import-import)). Otherwise, you should probably just import all of the methods and classes you will use as a tuple in the import statement:

```
from subprocess import STDOUT, popen, call
```

Comment: Agreed that it works, but what if you have many such constants? for ex, in other submodules to be used? 
There should be a way to use the constants defined in a submodule without using "from module import CONST"

Comment: with version 3.1 and above this will not work anymore. still get error `stdout not defined`

Comment: I cannot reproduce the error you mentioned. Just successfully ran the import (changing popen to Popen) with Python 3.7. Maybe you forgot to capitalize STDOUT?