# difference between __all__ and from bar import * in __init__.py in package

Tags: python, import, module, package, init

can someone please tell me what the differnce between using these two in my `__init__.py` in my package? And which is better to use?

```
__all__ = ['functions']

from functions import *
```

Comment: Start [here](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html#importing-from-a-package).

Comment: Those two lines do two different things: Setting `__all__` defines *which* members will be imported when using the `from … import *` syntax to import from that module.

Comment: @poke so say my structure was
main.py
**this_pkg/
  __init.py__
   myfile.py**  (inside has myfunctn)
and in my '__init__.py' I would put '__all__ = ['myfile.py']'
then in main.py I would put 'from this_pkg import *'
then I should be able to say in main.py 'myfunctn(myarg)' but I can't

Comment: See [Can someone explain `__all__` in Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/44834/216074) and [What exactly does “import *” import?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2360724/216074).

Answer (score 0):

The difference between the possible two statements in the script bar__init__.py is what scope the sub-packages or modules under bar are imported into.  If the package bar contains the sub-package named functions, the statement

from functions import *

in bar__init__.py will import the functions sub-package into the scope of the bar package, and it can be accessed using the reference

bar.functions

in Python code that imports bar.  If bar__init__.py contains the code

**all** = [functions]

then Python code containing the code

from bar import *

will define the sub-package as functions (with no reference to bar.)

Either method can be used to reference the contents of the sub-package functions, but the syntax is different.

Answer (score -4):

```
print(len(globals()))
import sys
print(len(globals()))
from sys import *
print(len(globals()))
```

OUTPUT:

```
8
9
67
```