# after doing "from tkinter import *" why ttk is not defined?

Tags: python, shell, import, tkinter, ttk

After doing `from tkinter import *` why is `ttk` not defined? What does `*` mean?

```
>>> from tkinter import *
>>> root = Tk()
>>> asd = ttk.Treeview(root)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File <"pyshell#4">, line 1, in <module>
    asd = ttk.Treeview(root)
NameError: name 'ttk' is not defined
```

If I do `from tkinter import ttk`, then there is no problem. On using `*`, `ttk` must have been fetched. Then why is there an error?

Comment: *"On using `*`, `ttk` must have been fetched."* - no, that's not correct. `ttk` isn't exposed in the module's [`__init__.py`](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/3.5/Lib/tkinter/__init__.py). If you don't know what `*` means in this context, see http://stackoverflow.com/q/2360724/3001761.

Answer (score 1):

What follows below is just elaborating on [jonrsharpe](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3001761/jonrsharpe)'s great comment that I think answers the question.

Python's `from package import *` indeed looks deceptively like it imports *everything* from said package, but **this is not the case**. [The docs](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html#packages) say:

> The import statement uses the following convention: if a package’s
>   `__init__.py` code defines a list named `__all__`, it is taken to be the list of module names that should be imported when from package import
>   * is encountered.

So if there is an `__init__.py` file in the package directory (it has to, otherwise it's not gonna be imported anyway) and it contains a list named `__all__` than this list's contents are treated as module names to be imported into the calling module's namespace.

What happens if `__all__` variable is not defined in `__init__.py`? Paraphrasing a further paragraph from the docs:

> If `__all__` is not defined, the statement `from package import *`
>   **does not import all submodules** from the package into the
>   current namespace; it only ensures that the package has
>   been imported (possibly running any initialization code in
>   `__init__.py`) and then imports whatever names are defined in the package. This includes any names defined (and submodules explicitly
>   loaded) by `__init__.py`. It also includes any submodules of the package
>   that were explicitly loaded by previous import statements.

If you want a good example where understanding this is crucial, head over to [video #20](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-tbWoZSi3LU) introducing GUI programming with TkInter in [Derek Banas's excellent Python YT series.](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLGLfVvz_LVvTn3cK5e6LjhgGiSeVlIRwt)

Answer (score 0):

The official [python documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/tkinter.ttk.html) reveals the answer

You can either do

```
from tkinter import ttk
```

Or

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.ttk import *
```

The second method overrides the 'original' tkinter widgets with the ttk versions. So just doing `from tkinter import *` means that you want to use the 'original' widgets.