# How can I use the content of a imported module in Python without having to write the module's file name every time?

Tags: java, python, python-3.x

For instance, in Java, when we import some class we can access the content of the class without having to write the file name. Something like this:

```
import structures.Node;

public class JavaExample {
//then I can call Node directly
Node node = new Node();
}
```

But in Python, when I want to do the same thing I have to do this:

```
import node

class PythonExample:
    # have to write node. first
    my_node = node.Node()
```

Is there a way to call the Node class without the 'node.', like we do in Java?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're going to be using something from that module frequently then you can import it specifically from the module and then reference it without the name:

```
from random import randint 
randint(1,10)
```

Or you can shorten the module name for convenience:

```
import random as r
r.randint(1,10)
```

Comment: Thank's a lot... Thats exactly what I was looking for!

Answer (score 1):

In Python, you'll conventionally use the 'node.' but it's often shortened to save keystrokes. For example:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
```

Comment: @RoryDaulton Thanks, fixed!

Answer (score 1):

The methods described by Chase G. and Jessica are generally what you want to do. For completeness' sake, the direct analog to what you're doing in Java would be `from node import *`. This is generally considered to be bad form due to namespace pollution among other things(1)(2)

(1): [Why is "import *" bad?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2386714/why-is-import-bad)
(2): [What exactly does "import *" import?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2360724/what-exactly-does-import-import)