# Import functions from one python file to another

Tags: python, function, file, import

Say i have a python file called `a.py` with the functions x,y,z.

I want to import them to a new file called `b.py`

I tried: `from a import *`   AND   `from a import all` with no luck.

I can just do it separately: `from a import x` , `from a import y` ....

How can i import them ALL at once?

Comment: you can do `import a` and then call function `a.x()`

Comment: `from a import *` should work fine, unless you have, for example, defined `__all__` in `a` somehow.  If that is not the case then we'll need more information.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can import a file and then use the functions on that file using the import name before the function name.

```
import example #this import the entire file named example.py

example.myfunction() #this call a function from example file
```

Comment: How does this relate to the question? Why does `from a import x` work and not `from a import *`?.

Comment: it imports all functions of a file to be used from a different file. And as bonus I added the proper way to call those imported functions. That covers the entire question O,o

Comment: Actually, you're right. `import *` is not a good idea but I'm curious as to why it doesn't work in this case.

Comment: I am not sure. Is hard to tell without checking the real code. It might be that * is for modules or packages, while the OP may not have a `__init__` in there and just a simple .py file with a method or two in no particular order. I need to research this also as I never seen that behaviour before (never tried to be honest).  
__Edit:__ found this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2360724/what-exactly-does-import-import