# Why does this "from bar import *" pollute my namespace with a name not defined in the imported module?

Tags: python, python-import

I thought I understood [what "import *" did](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2360724/what-exactly-does-import-import) and [its potential dangers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2386714/why-is-import-bad), but obviously not.

I've got:

**foo.py:**

```
from datetime import datetime
from bar import *
print(datetime.now())
```

**bar.py:**

```
import datetime
```

The result of running foo.py is an exception:

> AttributeError: module 'datetime' has no attribute 'now'

`datetime` is a module, but `datetime.datetime` is a type. `from datetime import datetime` makes it so that `datetime` in foo.py refers to the type, but the subsequent `from bar import *` somehow makes it again refer to the module.

Removing the `from bar import *` makes the exception go away.

But why does `from bar import *` pollute my namespace with the module `datetime`? `datetime` is a module imported in `bar`, but it isn't defined there. What am I missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `bar` module *does* define a name `datetime`. The statement

```
import datetime
```

creates a module-level `datetime` variable in the `bar` module and binds the variable to the `datetime` module. `import *` picks up this name the same way it picks up other names.

`import *` doesn't care about where objects were created. It doesn't care that the `datetime` module itself comes from some other file. A `datetime` name exists in `bar`, so that name gets imported.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation; it makes sense. I guess I thought that modules from imports were somehow not picked up from an import *, but with your explanation, I guess that would be even weirder.