# Can I use one import statement to replace the 4?

Tags: python

```
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense
from keras.wrappers.scikit_learn import KerasClassifier
from keras.utils import np_utils
```

Is this the same as:

```
from keras *
```

In Java, I can do this shortcut, and it looks much cleaner. I am learning Python.

Comment: In a way, this question is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3615125/should-wildcard-import-be-avoided

Comment: Have a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2360724/what-exactly-does-import-import Basically the `from keras import *` statement imports much more things than just those in your first four rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess it's ok, but be aware you'll have to re-type lots of lines to do stuff you want, and your code can be a little messy with that... example:

```
import keras
keras.models.sequential()
keras.layers.Dense()
keras.wrappers.scikit_learn (...)
```

In a big code this would be really confusing and annoying to read. I used to have the same habit as yours, but with time I lost it :D

Answer (score 1):

I believe `from keras *` is not valid syntax, but you can do:

```
from keras import *
```

*Note*: PEP-8 recommends that you avoid wildcard imports...

> "...as they make it unclear which names are present in the namespace,
>   confusing both readers and many automated tools. There is one
>   defensible use case for a wildcard import, which is to republish an
>   internal interface as part of a public API (for example, overwriting a
>   pure Python implementation of an interface with the definitions from
>   an optional accelerator module and exactly which definitions will be
>   overwritten isn't known in advance)."

But then you need to prefix a call with the submodule it comes from, for example:

```
f = layers.Dense(1)
```

Comment: If you are going to suggest that line of code, you should also mention why it is not recommended to use it

Comment: I dropped in the PEP-8 on that topic in an edit to my answer @jberrio and thanks for the constructive criticism!

Comment: A wildcard import like `from keras import *` will only import was is available in the `keras/__init__.py` file. Many libraries create names for convenience imports there, but not all. Submodules and packages are automatically imported.