# Error: NameError: name 'json' is not defined

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
from json import *
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import os

fp=open("data1.json","r")
data=json.loads(fp)
print(data)

s=pd.Series(data,index=[1,2])
print(s)
```

Error

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It has has to do with how you imported the json module. By using the `*` notation, you are importing everything in the json module. When importing a module in this way, you do not need to specify the module a function came from.

When importing, you have two options, import the module (and reference the module name when using it), or import everything in the module (and **not** reference the module name when using it).

As an aside, it is generally recommended to use the first method (`import json`). (reference [Why is “import *” bad?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2386714/why-is-import-bad)
 and [What exactly does “import *” import?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2360724/what-exactly-does-import-import)).

Also note the `with` statement to ensure the file is properly closed when reading is finished.

```
# Option 1: (recommended)
import json

with open("data1.json", "w") as f:
    data = json.loads(f.read())
print(data)
```

```
# OR Option 2: (not recommended, but shown to illustrate differences in usage)

from json import *
with open("data1.json", "w") as f:
    data = loads(f.read())
print(data)
```