# from sympy import * In this line what is the function of * that represented after import

Tags: python, python-3.x

In e.g.

```py
from sympy import *
```

what is the meaning of `import *`?

Comment: This is really basic stuff that is covered in the python [tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/index.html). See the section [Importing * From a Package](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html#importing-from-a-package).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What exactly does "import \*" import?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2360724/what-exactly-does-import-import)

Answer (score 2):

It simply says that you want all of the module's variables imported into your module's namespace. if `scipy` has a variable `foo`, you get the same object with the same name in your module's "global" namespace. Modules can modify what "all" means using the special variable `__all__`.