# Cannot import pytrends?

Tags: python

I am trying to use the pytrends package but I am getting the error when trying to import with:

```
from pytrends.request import TrendReq
```

I am receiving this error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-23-151901f76e59> in <module>
----> 1 from pytrends.request import TrendReq

~/Documents/pytrends.py in <module>
----> 1 from pytrends.request import TrendReq
      2 import requests

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pytrends.request'; 'pytrends' is not a package
```

I have installed the required packages as below:

```
pip install pytrends
pip install pandas
pip install lxml
pip install requests
```

How could I get pytrends to work?

Comment: Try ```from pytrends import *```  related topic for ```import *``` https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2360724/what-exactly-does-import-import

Comment: Are you running it on jupyter notebook? Are you sure pip is being run from the right environment?

Comment: Is your environment name or any script file has the same name as pytrends?

Comment: it turns out it is because my script name is pytrends.py...why would this cause an issue?