# tkinter Menubar on Canvas

Tags: python, tkinter, canvas, menubar

I have written the below code to create a tkinter form with a menu bar, I am using the canvas widget to arrange all the buttons and labels, however I am not able to show the menubar on the canvas
below is the code I have written to do this:

```
from tkinter import *
import tkinter as tk

window = Tk() 
window.title("test")
window.geometry("500*500")
canvas1 = Canvas(window, width= 500, height= 500, bg = 'midnight blue')
menubar = tk.Menu(window)
filemenu = tk.Menu(menubar, tearoff=0)
filemenu.add_command(label="New",command=dosomething)
filemenu.add_command(label="Edit",command=dosomething)
button1 = tk.Button(window, text="Say Hello")

window.config(menu = menubar)
canvas1.create_window(100,100, window = button1)
window.mainloop()
```

I am not sure how to display the menubar on the top of the canvas, please help on how to do this.

Comment: In the code you provided, you are not displaying `canvas1`  in your window, you forgot to pack or grid it.

Comment: Also, you are not adding `filemenu` to your `menubar` so it is empty.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several issues in your code:

1. You are not displaying your canvas, don't forget to `pack` or `grid` it in the window.
2. You create a sub-menu called `filemenu` but you don't add it in your `menubar`. Therefore `menubar` is empty, that's why you don't see it, even though `window.config(menu=menubar)` is the right way to display it in your window. Here is the missing line:

   ```
    menubar.add_cascade(label='File', menu=filemenu)
   ```
3. There is a typo in the window geometry: `window.geometry("500*500")` should be `window.geometry("500x500")`.
4. The lines

   ```
    from tkinter import *
    import tkinter as tk
   ```

   are redundant, you are importing `tkinter` twice. I advise you to remove `from tkinter import *` (see explanations here: [Why is "import *" bad?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2386714/why-is-import-bad), [What exactly does "import *" import?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2360724/what-exactly-does-import-import))

Here is the full code:

```
import tkinter as tk

def dosomething():
    print('do something')
    
window = tk.Tk() 
window.title("test")
window.geometry("500x500")
canvas1 = tk.Canvas(window, width=500, height=500, bg='midnight blue')
menubar = tk.Menu(window)
filemenu = tk.Menu(menubar, tearoff=0)
filemenu.add_command(label="New", command=dosomething)
filemenu.add_command(label="Edit", command=dosomething)
menubar.add_cascade(label='File', menu=filemenu)
button1 = tk.Button(window, text="Say Hello")

window.config(menu=menubar)
canvas1.create_window(100, 100, window=button1)
canvas1.pack()
window.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thanks j_4321 I got my mistake the code is working fine now cheers