# Python - why import * in package doesn't work?

Tags: python, python-import, grpc, python-packaging

Assume this package:

```
  mylibrary/
    ...
    setup.py
    service_stubs/
      __init__.py
      service_pb2.py
      service_pb2_grpc.py
```

I want that when I import the sub package, all the modules will be available on the package.
Tried to put in my `__init__.py`:

```
from . import *
```

And then using like so:

```
import service_stubs
service_stubs.service_pb2.something_inside_the_module
```

However this does not work, says `service_pb2` module not found. I have to
`import service_stubs.service_pb2` before for that to work.

If I change `__init__.py` to:

```
from . import service_pb2
```

Then it does work fine.

But, I don't want to explicitly import every module inside the package, since many modules will be there.

Why `from . import *` does not export name on the package, the same way as `from . import something`?

And what simple way will solve this?

Comment: You many find another SO post useful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2360724/what-exactly-does-import-import

Comment: Did not see an explanation for the difference