# import syntax in Python

Tags: python, import

Is there any difference between coding:

```
import turtle
```

and coding

```
from turtle import *
```

(Using module turtle as an example, I suppose the answer will be true for all modules.)

My understanding was that the * imports all methods in the module, so why use the longer syntax?

Comment: I think this topic answers everything you need to know about the importing conventions: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2360724/what-exactly-does-import-import

Comment: Sandertjuhh, thank you. That page was useful.