# I'm getting a NameError saying name 'Tk' is not defined when I'm trying to use Tkinter on VsCode

Tags: python, tkinter, visual-studio-code

When I'm trying to run a script to see if I can use `tkinter` on VsCode it throws a `NameError` saying `name 'Tk' is not defined`. Furthermore I can run it on IDLE and it runs just fine. I've been searching around to see if I can fix it but I still can't get it working. Do you have any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Here is the code:

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
myLabel = Label(root, text = 'Hello World!')
myLabel.pack()
```

Comment: Have you named the file `tkinter.py`? Because then it tries to import from itself. Also don't use `*` when importing, import either specific names or `import module` (`as md` ,can also use an alias), then prefix names from that module with `module.` (or `md.` if using an alias).

Comment: I have a file named tkinter.py, but I don't know if that's the correct tkinter file I got when I downloaded python.  What should I write instead if I don't want it to import from itself? Why should don't use "*" ? Thank you for your help!

Comment: You need to rename your own `tkinter.py` to something else.

Comment: There should NOT be a file called `tkinter.py`.  `tkinter` is a directory.  If you have a file called `tkinter.py`, that's what is screwing things up.

Comment: you can read about importing in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2360808/14531062)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do NOT name your file `tkinter.py` because the tkinter module you are trying to import is actually importing the file itself. And since there's no function called `Tk` in your file, you are getting that error. Rename the file to something else.

For example, rename it to `gui.py`.

Also, it's better to be **explicit** rather than **implicit** in python. So instead of

```
# Pollutes your namespace 
# May clash with the functions you define or functions of other libraries that you import

from tkinter import * 

root = Tk()
...
```

you should use

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
...
```

Here's an example of how it can clash with other namespaces:

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
Label = "hello"
Label1 = Label(gui, text=Label)
```

This results in an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "stackoverflow.py", line 98, in <module>
     Label1 = Label(gui, text=Label)
 TypeError: 'str' object is not callable
```

Comment: Your explicit/implicit comment is valid, but unfortunately, most of the `tkinter` tutorials date from 25 years ago, and still use the `from tkinter import *` thing.  It's an uphill battle.

Comment: I changed the name of the file and now I could run it. Thank you for the help. Where can I learn about tkinter if most of the tutorials are old?

Comment: @lilted If doesn't really matter if tutorials use the wildcard import, when you follow along instead of using the function (i.e `Label()`), just do `tk.Label()`.  There's also a pretty nice course I found using the `import tkinter as tk` import, https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xuXYKhdoTsw

Comment: @lilted This is the course I learned with (It's free!): https://edube.org/study/pcpp1-3

Comment: @lilted personally I use this reference (it still has some of the old names for a few modules but otherwise it's great): https://anzeljg.github.io/rin2/book2/2405/docs/tkinter/, there is also an archive from effbot.org: http://web.archive.org/web/20201111171246/https://effbot.org/tkinterbook/ as well as little less comprehensive IMO but it has great examples and stuff this: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_gui_programming.htm