# import * modules clarification

Tags: python, import

The [Python Tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html#compiled-python-files), mentions this following statement within the chapter 6. Modules.

*"It also includes any submodules of the package that were explicitly loaded by previous import statements."*

The questions is, if there were no previous import statements

```
import sound.effects.echo
import sound.effects.surround
```

,would echo and surround be not imported? If yes, how does using the two above mentioned import statements ***exactly*** change the behaviour of import *?

Answer (score 0):

Dotted module names do not imply the existence of any attributes on a containing package, despite the identical syntax. The package `sound` does not necessarily have an attribute named `effects`, though the module name `sound.effects` refers to a module named `effects` contained in the package `sound`.

`import sound.effects.echo` does several things:

1. Binds the package `sound` to the name `sound` in the current scope
2. Binds the module `sound.effects` to an attribute named `effects` on the module `sound`.
3. Binds the module `sound.effects.echo` to an attribute named `echo` on the module `sound.effects`.

The statement `from sound.effects import *` does the following:

1. Imports the module `sound.effects`, but does *not* bind it to any name in the current scope
2. For each module global defined in `sound.effects.__all__`, or all module globals not prefixed with `_` if `__all__` is not defined, define a new name in the global scope and bind that name to the correponding module global.

Answer (score 0):

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2360724/what-exactly-does-import-import) answers it nicely.

Basically, `import *` will import everything in the module, *except any submodules.*

Your code will import the main `sound` module, as well as the `echo` and `surround` submodules.

This is a [good example](https://tenthousandmeters.com/blog/python-behind-the-scenes-11-how-the-python-import-system-works/#:%7E:text=For%20this%20reason%2C%20Python%20allows,module%20names%20to%20contain%20dots.&text=it%20first%20imports%20the%20module,submodule%20as%20a%20module%27s%20attribute.).